# How do I change the ID of a HTML element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I am modifying the ID of an HTML `div` element client side with JavaScript. The following code works OK in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox/2.0.0.20. It does work in more recent versions of Firefox.

```
document.getElementById('one').id = 'two';
```

Can anyone tell me:

1. Why this doesn't work in FireFox.
2. How to make this work in FireFox.

To clarify, I'm changing the element ID to reference a different style in an external style sheet. The style is applied in IE but not in FF.

Comment: Should work find in firefox - what makes you think it isn't?

Comment: This works for me in Firefox, are you getting a JavaScript error? Can you post more code examples?

Comment: Download Firebug and have a look to see what error is thrown in the console window

Comment: Works for me on FF 3.5.4, WinXP SP 3, `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091007 Firefox/3.5.4 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)`

Comment: When exactly are you doing this? Are you making sure that the DOM is ready first? Try a window.onload handler or put your script after the said element.

Answer (score 54):

It does work in Firefox (*including `2.0.0.20`*). See http://jsbin.com/akili (add `/edit` to the url to edit):

```
<p id="one">One</p>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('one').id = 'two'; return false">Link2</a>
```

The first click changes the `id` to `"two"`, the second click errors because the element with `id="one"` now can't be found!

Perhaps you have another element *already* with `id="two"` (FYI [you can't have more than one element with the same `id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)).

Answer (score 16):

That seems to work for me:

```
<html>
<head><style>
#monkey {color:blue}
#ape {color:purple}
</style></head>
<body>
<span id="monkey" onclick="changeid()">
fruit
</span>
<script>
function changeid ()
{
var e = document.getElementById("monkey");
e.id = "ape";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected behaviour is to change the colour of the word "fruit".

Perhaps your document was not fully loaded when you called the routine?

Answer (score 10):

You can modify the `id` without having to use `getElementById`

Example:

```html
<div id="One" onclick="One.id = 'Two'; return false;">One</div>
```

You can see it here: http://jsbin.com/elikaj/1/

Tested with Mozilla Firefox 22 and Google Chrome 60.0

Comment: These days it's (rightfully) considered bad practise to [target elements by there global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325221/why-dont-we-just-use-element-ids-as-identifiers-in-javascript). Same goes for [inline event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html).