# Click button on load event

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have the following javascript -

```
function onLoad() {
    if (!(document.applets && document.VLVChart && document.VLVChart.isActive())) {
        setTimeout('onLoad()', 200);
        return;
    }
    objChart = document.VLVChart;
    PollEvent();
}

function fan() {
    objChart.reorganize();
}
```

And then when the HTML page is loaded -

```
<body onLoad="onLoad()">
```

and have a button within the HTML that execute the `fan()` function -

```
<input type='button' value='Fan' onClick='fan();'>
```

Is it possible for me to activate the `fan()` function within the onload event so that a user does ont have to click the button?

**EDIT**
After trying the provided answers, on debugging the code breaks on the line -

```
objChart.reorganize();
```

Within the `fan()` function with the error -

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'reorganize': object is null or undefined
```

This is odd as when I manually click the button on the page, the function works fine.

**Solution**
After much head scratching I have realised that I was trying to load the `fan()` function before the page (and more specifically the objChart) had fully loaded. Hence why adding the function in the `onLoad` event was not working. I added a `setTimeout` -

```
function Fan()
{
setTimeout(function(){objChart.reorganize();},3000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body onload='onLoad(); fan();'>...
```

However inline JS is best avoided and you would do well to begin looking into centralised event management. There are various advantages to this.

[**An answer I wrote yesterday**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-on-event-handler-attributes-in-modern-semantic-html-a-good-or-a/11742769#11742769) to another question outlines why this is. Something like jQuery makes this trivial if it's new for you.

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('load', function() {
        onLoad();
        fan();
    });
});
```

Comment: Its odd, I have tried both your first answer on putting the fan() function into the onload event, and also @feeela calling the fan() function in the onload function. For some reason neither seem work?

Comment: Both are definitely sound. The latter requires that you have jQuery loaded into the page. Any console errors? Always check the console with JS issues. If the problem persists, post a JS Fiddle so we can see.

Comment: If `reorganize()` is not a function that is a separate issue from the one you asked about. You asked how to invoke `fan()` onload and I provided that. This new issue means something isn't being loaded or declared properly.

Comment: I think this is a timing issue, I think I am trying to execute fan before the page has properly loaded...

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I assume you didn't even have tried. Just call that function from within your `onLoad()`-function:

```
function onLoad()
{
    fan();
    /* … */
}
```

Comment: I had tried those before, I should have stated that in my question. It was down to a timing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use `<body onload='onLoad(); fan();'>` as Utkanos suggests.

If you use jQuery, you can also stick a script in the head containing:

```
$(function(){
   ...
});
```

The jQuery function actually fires earlier, as is explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).