# What is the equivalent of jQuery's .before() function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, equivalent

What is the equivalent of [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) in Javascript?

Comment: In its simplest form, `a.before(b)` is `a.parentNode.insertBefore(b,a)`

Comment: [MDN: Node.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

Comment: You can always look at [the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js)

Comment: I believe you mean `.insertbefore()`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you should post that as an answer.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a96d5bed58f2b30f97d6dd2f5691cd890f62b75f/src/manipulation.js#L342

Comment: Check the jquery source https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a96d5bed58f2b30f97d6dd2f5691cd890f62b75f/src/manipulation.js#L342

Comment: Seems it is a duplicate...  check @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315948/insert-html-before-element-in-javascript-without-jquery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`node.insertBefore()` is pretty much the equivalent : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore

```
$('#id').before('something');
//equivalent 
var node = document.getElementById('id');
node.parentNode.insertBefore('something', node);
```

Here what jQuery does : https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L6064

```
before: function() {
    return this.domManip( arguments, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.parentNode ) {
            this.parentNode.insertBefore( elem, this );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `insertBefore` in javascript

```
node.insertBefore(newnode, existingchild);
```

The example above will append newnode as a child of node, directly before the existingchild node.

Answer (score 0):

Ok these answers were a bit deceptive.  It’s a bit different using `node.insertBefore` than using the jQuery `.before()` method.

```
// jQuery
$('.element').before('<span class="class-name">Some text</span>');

// Pure JS
var _$element = document.querySelector('.element');
var _$new = document.createElement('span');
_$new.outerHTML = '<span class="class-name">Some text</span>';
_$element.parentNode.insertBefore(_$new, _$element);
```

---

If you are wondering why it looks so simple in the [jQuery snippet](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L6064)

```
before: function() {
    return this.domManip( arguments, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.parentNode ) {
            this.parentNode.insertBefore( elem, this );
        }
    });
}
```

Well notice that it starts with `this.domManip`. It is doing stuff behind the scenes in that function that abstracts away the element creation stuff.