# How to wrap single qoute(')around variables inside jQuery html() method

Tags: jquery

I need to use single qoute to wrap 2 valiables inside .html() method in jQuery. I want to know how to fix this ?

```
$("#mydiv").html('<a class="accset_chg_ressid" href="#" onclick="changeit(var1,var2);">Change Change it</a>');
```

var1 and var2  is none numeric variable, so it need single qoute to wrap it. But How to fix this ?

Comment: You can escape with \  __HOWEVER__ , don't have inline handlers inside HTML you add _especially_ since you're using jQuery so you have a crossbrowser `.click` method. Also, don't build HTML like that, either create it normally (using `$("$<a/>")` or `document.createElement`) or use proper templates.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of $("$<a/>") method or the best way to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked in the comment for a better way to do this, so here is one:

```
var $a = $("<a></a>").addClass("accset_chg_ressid").
                     attr("href","#").
                     click(function(e){// changeit should probably be here
                         return changeit(var1,var2); 
                     }).text("Change Change it");
//cache the reference later
$("#myDiv").empty().append($a);//add to the parent
```

Note that this way you have a reference to the element (for further manipulation, removal etc). You also don't have any 'string magic'.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. I want to know what is the reason I should not use inline method as you mentioned above ?

Comment: @user3104858 less string magic, actual context if you have a problem with the onclick handler, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/ (and a million other answers on the subject). Ever tried debugging an inline handler? Or changing the content of magic strings like that?

Comment: This is very new knowlege for me. But thank you for this. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by just adding the escape `\`. Check below.

```
$("#mydiv").html('<a class="accset_chg_ressid" href="#" onclick="changeit(\'var1\',\'var2\');">Change Change it</a>');
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer I actually have tried this , it works..but the comment above: Benjamin Gruenbaum said: this is not the best way to do. What should I do ?