# JQuery hide the error div when typing inside the textbox

Tags: jquery

I have error div that will appear when the form is submitted to the server,

```
<p>
    <input id="first_name" class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" onkeyup="remove_error()" placeholder="First Name"> \
    <span id="error_first_name" class="err alert alert-danger">
        The first name may only contain letters.
        <br>
        The first name must be at least 2 characters.
    </span>
</p>
```

I have this code:

```
$("#first_name").keyup(function(e)
{
    $("#error_first_name").fadeOut();
});
```

I am planning to change it to

```
<input id="first_name" class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" onkeyup="remove_error()"placeholder="First Name">
```

so that I can just call a function where it will remove the error in the same div with 'err' class.
This is do-able if I will type in all input item 1 by 1, how can I make it to be a function where I can just call and remove the said div?

```
    function remove_error()
    {
        $(this).next(".err").fadeOut(); //get next div with err class and fadeout
    }
```

Comment: I took the div tag I got from the bootstrap sample. if I switch it to span it becomes giberish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just define a class for your element and it's validator , then use sibling to fadeout the validator element on keyup

```
$(".validate").keyup(function (e) {
    console.log($(this).siblings('.validator'));
    $(this).siblings('.validator').fadeOut();
});
```

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mfarouk/6vgnfam7/

Comment: I will be using this one. thanks for the other answers.

Comment: @Ponce `.siblings()` isn't the right choice for what you've shown in question. It'll search the entire parent for matching elements while in reality you just want to access the following element. Unnecessary `DOM` traversal is a bad practice. Also it doesn't answer how to use the inline handler or why you should not use it. BTW which answer to accept is entirely upto you.

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to use inline event handlers. you can use a common class for the textboxes and do:

```
$(".commonClass").keyup(function(e){
  $(this).next(".err").fadeOut();
});
```

---

If you must use inline handler, then you should pass a reference to the element using `this` keyword:

```
<input id="first_name" class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" onkeyup="remove_error(this)"placeholder="First Name">
```

And you can use it in the function:

```
 function remove_error(elm){
    $(elm).next(".err").fadeOut(); //get next div with err class and fadeout
}
```

---

Read: [Why is inline event handler attributes is a bad idea in modern semantic HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/2333214)

Comment: this doesnt seem to work.

   $(".remove_err_onkeyup").keyup(function(e){
    
    $(this).next('.err').fadeOut();
   });