# Vue: How do I call multiple functions with @click?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

How can I call multiple functions in a single `@click`? (aka `v-on:click`)?

So far I tried

- Splitting the functions with a semicolon: `<div @click="fn1('foo');fn2('bar')"> </div>`;
- Using several `@click`: `<div @click="fn1('foo')" @click="fn2('bar')"> </div>`;

and as a workaround, I can just create a handler:

```
<div v-on:click="fn3('foo', 'bar')"> </div>

function fn3 (args) { 
  fn1(args);
  fn2(args);
}
```

But sometimes this isn't nice. What would be the proper method/syntax?

Comment: I strongly believe that my answer is more Vue-like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58744983/7854594

Answer (score 401, accepted):

On Vue 2.3 and above you can do this:

```
<div v-on:click="firstFunction(); secondFunction();"></div>
// or
<div @click="firstFunction(); secondFunction();"></div>
```

Comment: are the methods guaranteed to execute in order?

Comment: This produces a warning on Vue.js v2.6.14:
```unreachable code after return statement```

If that bothers anyone - you can always try something like this:
```<div @click="()=>{firstFunction(); secondFunction();}"></div>```

Comment: Not recommended for those who have `prettier` with `"semi": false` because will remove the semicolon. I recommend the plus sign between the name of the functions.

Comment: This works while leaving away the function braces `()` did not work.

Comment: Does not work in Vue3. useToggle is worthless without a callback

Comment: I strongly believe that my answer is more Vue-like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58744983/7854594

Answer (score 51):

First of all you can use the short notation `@click` instead of `v-on:click` for readability purposes.

Second You can use a click event handler that calls other functions/methods as @Tushar mentioned in his comment above, so you end up with something like this :

```
<div id="app">
   <div @click="handler('foo','bar')">
       Hi, click me!
   </div>
</div>

<!-- link to vue.js !--> 
<script src="vue.js"></script>

<script>
   (function(){
        var vm = new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            methods:{
                method1:function(arg){
                    console.log('method1: ',arg);
                },
                method2:function(arg){
                    console.log('method2: ',arg);
                },
                handler:function(arg1,arg2){
                    this.method1(arg1);
                    this.method2(arg2);
                }
            }
        })
    }()); 
</script>
```

Comment: Not helpful if you use `useToggle` in `@vueuse/core`

Comment: I strongly believe that my answer is more Vue-like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58744983/7854594

Answer (score 46):

If you want something a little bit more readable, you can try this:

```
<button @click="[click1($event), click2($event)]">
  Multiple
</button>
```

To me, this solution feels more Vue-like hope you enjoy

Comment: also can do @click="click1($event); click2($event)".
Here the main point is adding explicit event argument to the handler function. This way each method will get the same payload or the original event data.
Important for the cases when you listen to custom event from Child component

Answer (score 28):

updated dec-2021

you need to separate with a comma
like this:

```
<button @click="open(), onConnect()">Connect Wallet</button>
```

Answer (score 15):

to add an anomymous function to do that may be an alternative:

```
<div v-on:click="return function() { fn1('foo');fn2('bar'); }()"> </div>
```

Comment: An ES6 alternative:

    @click="() => { function1(parameters); function2(parameters); }"

Comment: Important note: if one of your nested functions need `$event` as an arg, you'll need to pass it as a parameter to your new function to be used inside of it. Eg. `($event) => {func1($event); func2('x');}`

Answer (score 11):

## Separate into pieces.

### Inline:

```js
<div @click="f1() + f2()"></div>
```

### OR: Through a composite function:

```js
<div @click="f3()"></div> 

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  // ...
  methods: {
    f3: function() { f1() + f2(); }
    f1: function() {},
    f2: function() {}
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

This simple way to do
    v-on:click="firstFunction(); secondFunction();"

Comment: I believe this will break the compiler and not render. Just tried it - broke.

Comment: I can see below it works for some, but breaks in 2.6.6 for me.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to add one small missing bit here which I felt missing in all of the answers above; that is you actually need to call the method rather than just passing its name as callable, when want to add multiple click handlers.

This might come as a surprise since Vue allows passing a callable to the `click` handler.

**This works**

```
<div><button @click="foo(); bar();">Button1</button></div>
<div><button @click="foo">Button2</button></div>
```

**This does not**

```
<div><button @click="foo; bar;">Button3</button></div>
```

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7gqs6fn0/)

Answer (score 8):

This works for me when you need to open another dialog box by clicking a button inside a dialogue box and also close this one. Pass the values as params with a comma separator.

```
<v-btn absolute fab small slot="activator" top right color="primary" @click="(addTime = true),(ticketExpenseList = false)"><v-icon>add</v-icon></v-btn>
```

Answer (score 6):

in Vue 2.5.1 for button works

```
 <button @click="firstFunction(); secondFunction();">Ok</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on ES6 with anonymous functions:

```
<button @click="() => { function1(); function2(); }"></button>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Vue` event handling only allows for single function calls. If you need to do multiple ones you can either do a wrapper that includes both:

```
<div @click="handler"></div>
////////////////////////////
handler: function() { //Syntax assuming its in the 'methods' option of Vue instance
    fn1('foo');
    fn2('bar');
}
```

**EDIT**

Another option is to edit the first handler to have a callback and pass the second in.

```
<div @click="fn1('foo', fn2)"></div>
////////////////////////////////////
fn1: function(value, callback) {
    console.log(value);
    callback('bar');
},
fn2: function(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Html:

```
<div id="example">
  <button v-on:click="multiple">Multiple</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    name: 'Vue.js'
  },
  // define methods under the `methods` object
  methods: {
    multiple: function (event) {
      this.first()
      this.second()
    }
    first:  function (event) {
      //yourstuff
    }
    second: function (event) {
      //yourstuff
    }
  }
})

vm.multiple()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
<div @click="f1(), f2()"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Simply do like below:**

- with `$event`:

  ```
  <div @click="function1($event, param1); function2($event,param1);"></div>
  ```
- without `$event`:

  ```
  <div @click="function1(param1); function2(param1);"></div>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like

```
<button v-on:click="Function1(); Function2();"></button>
```

OR

```
<button @click="Function1(); Function2();"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd add, that you can also use this to call multiple emits or methods or both together by separating with ; semicolon

```
  @click="method1(); $emit('emit1'); $emit('emit2');"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking this solution and used different methods and I found this one best for me. Just shared with you
***You can use template literals to use multiple function in one event in vuejs

```
<div @click="`${firstFunction() ${secondFunction() ${thirdFucntion()}`"></div>
```

Note:I am using vue3.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't actually execute the three function when the component is rendered (rather than when this `div` is clicked)?

Answer (score 1):

You can write javascript as a normal multiline:

```
@click="(event) => {
          console.log(event);
          console.log("Second log");
        }"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

you can, however, do something like this :

```
<div onclick="return function()
              {console.log('yaay, another onclick event!')}()" 
              @click="defaultFunction"></div>
```

yes, by using native onclick html event.