# Vue.js- Calling a function AND running an expression with v-on:click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186374/871404) shows how to call two functions with `v-on` by doing `v-on:click="firstFunction(); secondFunction();"`. But in my project, I need to call a function besides an expression imposed by `Vuetify`. The default `Vuetify` code is:

```
<v-btn color="success" @click="dialog = false">
  Save Row
</v-btn>
```

However beside the expression dialog = false, I need to call a certain function `newRow()`. I tried:

```
 <v-btn color="success" @click="newRow(); dialog = false">
    Save Row
</v-btn>
```

But that breaks the `Vuetify` functionality (the dialog doesn't close anymore). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `newRow()` method add :

```
      methods:{
          newRow(){
           //here put the logic to add new row 
           //and after that close the dialog box
           this.dialog=false;
           }
      ...
     }
```

and call it in the template like :

```
  <v-btn color="success" @click="newRow()">
    Save Row
  </v-btn>
```