# Cannot execute scoped slot and function in the same event Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css

I have the following code which uses this [VueTailwind](https://www.vue-tailwind.com/) package:

```html
<t-dropdown>
<div
    slot="trigger"
    slot-scope="{mousedownHandler, focusHandler, blurHandler, keydownHandler}"
>
    <button
        id="reseller-menu"
        aria-label="User menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        @mousedown="mousedownHandler"
        @focus="focusHandler"
        @blur="blurHandler"
        @keydown="keydownHandler"
    >
        {{ $page.props.auth.user.reseller.name }}
        <icon icon="chevron-down" class-name="ml-2" />
    </button>
</div>

<div slot-scope="{ blurHandler }">
    <span v-for="user in users" :key="reseller.id" role="menuitem" class="block px-6 cursor-pointer py-2 hover:bg-indigo-500 hover:text-white"
         @click="changeUser(user.id); blurHandler">{{ user.name }}</span>
</div>
</t-dropdown>
```

However, the `blurHandler` is not executed whenever the `changeUser(user.id)` method (a method in the parent component which seems to execute fine) is added to the `@click` event. The only way I was able to solve this issue was to use two different events such as the following:

```html
<span v-for="user in users" :key="reseller.id" role="menuitem" class="block px-6 cursor-pointer py-2 hover:bg-indigo-500 hover:text-white"
         @click="changeUser(user.id)" @mouseup="blurHandler">{{ user.name }}</span>
```

How can I use both in the same event since [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744932/how-to-call-multiple-functions-with-click-in-vue) doesn't seem to work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `v-on` value is a *function reference*, the template compiler transforms it into a function call, passing the event argument:

```html
<button @click="functionRef">

<!-- ...is transformed into: -->

<button @click="functionRef($event)">
```

But when the `v-on` value is an *expression*, the template compiler wraps it in a function:

```html
<button @click="onClick(); functionRef">

<!-- ...is transformed into: -->

<button @click="() => { onClick(); functionRef; }">
```

Notice `functionRef;` is not a function call, and effectively does nothing. To actually invoke the function in that expression, add the parentheses to make it a call:

```html
<button @click="onClick(); functionRef()">
```

So your markup should be:

```html
<div slot-scope="{ blurHandler }">
    <span v-for="user in users" ⋯                 
          @click="changeUser(user.id); blurHandler()">
        {{ user.name }}
    </span>
</div>
```

Also note `slot-scope` has been [deprecated for `v-slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Deprecated-Syntax), as of 2.6.0.

Comment: Indeed, if `blurHandler` needs to access the event arg (e.g., to get the event source), the `$event` would have to be passed on as well.