# how to combine more than two functions into one for vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am looking to combine the functions of each different switches into one button so all lights are on when i click it, however, only two functions were executed when i clicked the button.

```
    <div><button v-on:click="onLightar(); onLightmngr(); onLightfy(); onLightmr(); onLightT(); onLightbr();" >Switch on all groundfloor lights </button></div>
```

Comment: perhaps the functions themselves are the issue - if two are executed (which two, you didn't mention) then there's nothing stopping you from doing 6 - personally, I'd write a function that runs those functions and call that function instead

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744932/how-to-call-multiple-functions-with-click-in-vue

Comment: can you provide function definitions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it simple and easy to understand, You can just call a single method on click and then invoke all the switches methods from that method.

In Template **:**

```
<div>
  <button v-on:click="switchOnAllLights">Switch on all groundfloor lights </button>
</div>
```

In Script **:**

```
switchOnAllLights() {
    this.onLightar();
    this.onLightmngr();
    this.onLightfy();
    this.onLightmr();
    this.onLightT();
    this.onLightbr();
}
```