# Run two functions on one button click in JS/VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im trying to run two functions; one being a 'reload page' and the other a 'copy to clipboard'. I have tried all the options on this page:

[How to call multiple functions with @click in vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744932/how-to-call-multiple-functions-with-click-in-vue/74457630?noredirect=1#comment131439691_74457630)

but none seem to work for me. Can anyone give me any pointers here? Any help is appreciated.

```
<button @click="reloadPage(); 
   copytheURL(URLcopyaddress);">Copy</button>



methods: {
    //reloads the page
    reloadPage() {
      window.location.reload();
    },
 //copy to clipboard
    async copytheURL(s) {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(s);
      alert("URL Copied!");
    },
},
```

Comment: How about creating another function that calls both functions and use this function on `@click`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put `window.location.reload();` inside the `async copytheURL(s)`? Right after `alert("URL Copied!");` ?

Comment: That was a really good idea! Unfortunately, it didn't quite work. I think it needs a time delay for the copy the URL. Im going to do a little research.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the reloading the page stops the javaScript run. replace the order, call the copy first and you should be fine

Comment: that's async behavior, so you never can expect the right chronology, wrap that in some promise or so

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I guessed that was the issue but didnt know how to solve it.

Comment: how would I do this exactly?

Comment: The easiest will be to call the reload function right after (bellow) the await

Answer (score 0):

Try like this below it will work like magic. The problem with your code is you  are trying call both functions in synchronus fashion. But ideally you should wait for the async function to complete and perform your synchronous function.

```
<button @click="copytheURL(URLcopyaddress).then(reloadPage)">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post! This only works if I click it twice. If I swap the functions to read <button  @click="reloadPage.then(copytheURL(URLcopyaddress))" > Copy                </button> then it does not work.