# Changing DIV visibility using javascript and a different image than was initially visible. Not using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visibility

I've tried to keep this relatively simple and I've spent the past 6 hours trying to get this work so if someone could correct me that'd be amazing.

**Desired Behaviour: Clicking image 1 should make it hide, image 2 is already there, clicking image 2 should make image 1 visible again. The user should be able to switch between each image multiple times.**

I have managed to make it so that the first image is no longer visible when it is clicked and it shows a second image (which I'm using instead of a button) when the second image is clicked it should display the first image again, I've tried resetting the div but I'm not sure on what the best means would be to make it visible again.

```html
 <!--Notice-->
    <div class="notice1">
    <style>.notice1 { position:fixed; bottom:0%; left:0%; z-index: 2;}</style>
    <img class="notice1" img draggable="false" onclick="this.style.display='none';" src="URL FOR IMAGE 1" width="100%" alt=""></div>

    <div class="Notice2">
    <style>.notice2 { position:fixed; bottom:0%; right: 0%; z-index: 1;}</style>
    <img class="notice2" img draggable="false" src="URL FOR IMAGE 2" width="2.5%" alt=""></div>
```

```html
    <script>
    function changeVisibility() {
        document.getElementById("notice1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
        
    function resetElement() {
        document.getElementById("notice2").style.visibility = "visible";>
    </script>
```

**The first snippet works and the first image disappears, I just need it to show the first image again when the second one is clicked.**

I'd tried to do this without scripts but I have no idea how. The first image disappears but I do not understand why clicking the first image won't make it disappear again. If you paste in your own image links you'll be able to see what I mean.

If someone could copy my code and make the changes directly that'd be amazing. I think there's something I'm missing and I can't find anything on this website that actually uses the same method as I.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code snippet won't run because it's missing the closing bracket for `resetElement()`. It's also missing a closing tag for the second `<div>` and you have a weird `<onclick="resetElement()">` tag at the end of your second `<img>` tag...

Comment: Sorry @Herohtar, I've updated it, The first image will disappear when clicked but clicking the second image doesn't bring the first one back.

Comment: And tell me, that `<onclick ...>` element... what the heck?

Comment: onclick would be an attribute to the image, maybe. Not an independent element.

Comment: the code snippet is all wrecked up you need to fix it first

Comment: yes that would be part of the `img` tag @Snowmonkey

Comment: @codingpassion Uh... that edit didn't fix anything. `>` is the ending symbol for a HTML tag, not a JavaScript function. Additionally, your `<img>` tags don't have closing tags. They should at least look like `<img class="..." ... />` (note the forward slash before the end)

Comment: I've tried to fix it @MuhammadOmerAslam I don't know why it isn't working. That's why I need help :(

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Comment: these are basic mistakes @codingpassion related to understanding the HTML structure and writing javascript code, and you need to look here how to create a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: At first glance this seemed like it might be a solid question, but it's clear that the OP doesn't have a basic understanding of JavaScript or even HTML. The issue is too broad to be answered here and should be closed.

Comment: It was a solid question, making websites is part of my day to day, this has just stumped me, I'd prefer it not be closed as I really need this fixed @Herohtar :(

Comment: I have included the desired behaviour in the question but I can repeat it here for you if you need it. Clicking image 1 should make it hide, image 2 is already there, clicking image 2 should make image 1 visible again. The user should be able to switch between each image multiple times. @Herohtar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a **number** of problems with your code:

- You've attempted to create a new tag to reset the element:
  `alt="ALT TAG"> <onclick="resetElement()">`
  You're probably looking for an **inline** event handler attribute (which would
  still be **[bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-is-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html)**). Ideally you should use **[`.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)** instead.
- Your images have an `img` attribute, which doesn't exist.
- You have inline `<style>` tags in the `<body>`. **[`<style>` must come inside `<head>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style)**. You can validate your markup with the **[W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/)**.
- You're targeting your elements with **[`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)**, when your elements **have** no ID. They have classes, so you're probably looking for **[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**. Note that this returns a **[`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, so you need to access the first result with `[0]`.
- You have a capital `N` in your declaration of `Notice2`, which should be `notice2`.
- Your `resetElement()` function is never called. Instead, you set the [**`display`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) for `notice1` inline (when you should be modifying the [**`visibility`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)).
- `notice1` is not invisible by default.
- You apply the notice classes to both the images and their respective parents, which is very likely unintentional.
- Your two images have different `width` attributes, which is also very likely to be unintentional.
- You have no toggle functionality. You want to swap the `visibility` rules when clicking on the second image.

Fixing all of that up gives you a working example, as can be seen in the following:

```js
var notice1 = document.getElementsByClassName("notice1")[0];
var notice2 = document.getElementsByClassName("notice2")[0];

notice1.onclick = function() {
  notice1.style.visibility = "hidden";
  notice2.style.visibility = "visible";
}

notice2.onclick = function() {
  notice2.style.visibility = "hidden";
  notice1.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
.notice1 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.notice2 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!--Notice-->
<div>
  <img class="notice1" draggable="false" src="http://placekitten.com/101" width="100%" alt="ALT TAG">
  <img class="notice2" draggable="false" src="http://placekitten.com/102" width="100%" alt="ALT TAG">
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yeah, but they're not elements by id, they're elements by class name. Other than that, dead bang.

Comment: That's great so far. The images are supposed to be different widths as the second image should be smaller. I need it so that when the first image is removed the second image is shown, I then need the user to be able to click the second image to show the first one again.

Comment: Kind of like a loop so that the user can switch back and forth, clicking image 1 will show image 2 and clicking image 2 will show image 1 again, if that makes any more sense @Snowmonkey

Comment: @Snowmonkey -- Correct; didn't notice that at first, was in a rush. Have a few minutes now and will correct all that :)

Comment: All that said, @ObsidianAge, great job summarising the vast majority of the issues to be addressed.

Comment: Yup, well done - except that the OP wants to have it toggle back and forth. You'll have to reverse the behavior in a click handler for the second image. Take a look at my example. But again, that particular behaviour is FAR behind the greater issues.

Comment: @Snowmonkey -- Sorry, yes, was still fixing up a few things haha. This functionality has also been added now :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge, you ROCK. Just sayin.

Answer (score 1):

I might look at something like this. First, remove the listeners from inline. then, Remove the hard-coded styles from the script (while you can do it, it will be easier to simply maintain a class than to toggle individual styles).  Adding the listeners by script is going to be easier to debug and edit. And have the listener's callback do whatever toggling you might need. Try this one!

```js
var notice1 = document.getElementsByClassName("notice1")[0];
var notice2 = document.getElementsByClassName("notice2")[0];

notice1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  notice1.classList.add("hidden");
  notice2.classList.remove("hidden");
})

notice2.addEventListener("click", function(){
  notice2.classList.add("hidden");
  notice1.classList.remove("hidden");
});
```

```css
.notice1 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.notice2 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--Notice-->
<div>
  <img class="notice1" draggable="false" src="http://placekitten.com/101" width="100%" alt="ALT TAG">
  <img class="notice2" draggable="false" src="http://placekitten.com/102" width="100%" alt="ALT TAG">
</div>
```

Comment: you've both saved my life, believe it or not part of my job and the reason I'm employed is to make websites. Sometimes my head just doesn't work, AMAZING! Thank You very much.

Comment: Well, @codingpassion, if ever you find you could use coding backup, drop me a line. I'm trying to break back into the field, and this seems a fun way to do it. ;)

Comment: I'll keep you in mind, kinda wish that I didn't do it all. Kinda a jack of all trades master of a few situation, I tried 9 different ways across 32 versions and gave up. When you look at something for so long you just can't spot errors, I usually check back after a week. Good Luck getting back into it @Snowmonkey

Comment: its how it goes -- when you get so deep into trying to find that one tree, you fail to notice that the entire forest is afire. Best of luck. Check my profile, my email is there.

Answer (score 0):

First I highly recommmend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

If I were to write this, it would be reusable and not limited to only 2 (of anything, could be div's, forms, whatever who cares).

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var cssIsHidden = 'is-hidden';
  $(".js-rotate").each((i,e) => {
    var $parent = $(e);
    $parent.find('.is-rotating')
      .addClass(cssIsHidden)
      .on('click', (e) => {
        var $rotate = $(e.currentTarget);
        $rotate.addClass(cssIsHidden);
        var next = $rotate.data('rotate-next');
        var $next = $parent.find(next);
        $next.removeClass(cssIsHidden);
      });
      
    var initial = $parent.data('rotate-first');
    $(initial).removeClass(cssIsHidden);
  });
});
```

```css
.is-hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-rotate" data-rotate-first=".ro-1">
  <img class="ro-1 is-rotating" 
       draggable="false" 
       src="http://placekitten.com/101"
       data-rotate-next=".ro-2">
  <img class="ro-2 is-rotating" 
       draggable="false" 
       src="http://placekitten.com/102"
       data-rotate-next=".ro-1">
</div>
```

Now you could pretty much add as many images (or any other element you want) in any number of locations:

```js
// Same exact code as above | no changes
$(document).ready(() => {
  var cssIsHidden = 'is-hidden';
  $(".js-rotate").each((i,e) => {
    var $parent = $(e);
    $parent.find('.is-rotating')
      .addClass(cssIsHidden)
      .on('click', (e) => {
        var $rotate = $(e.currentTarget);
        $rotate.addClass(cssIsHidden);
        var next = $rotate.data('rotate-next');
        var $next = $parent.find(next);
        $next.removeClass(cssIsHidden);
      });
      
    var initial = $parent.data('rotate-first');
    $(initial).removeClass(cssIsHidden);
  });
});
```

```css
.is-hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Multiple Images:
<div class="js-rotate" data-rotate-first=".ro-1">
  <img class="ro-1 is-rotating" 
       draggable="false" 
       src="http://placekitten.com/101"
       data-rotate-next=".ro-2">
  <img class="ro-2 is-rotating" 
       draggable="false" 
       src="http://placekitten.com/102"
       data-rotate-next=".ro-3">
  <img class="ro-3 is-rotating" 
       draggable="false" 
       src="http://placekitten.com/103"
       data-rotate-next=".ro-4">
  <img class="ro-4 is-rotating" 
       draggable="false" 
       src="http://placekitten.com/104"
       data-rotate-next=".ro-1">
</div>

Just two, but independant of the first set:
<div class="js-rotate" data-rotate-first=".ro-1">
  <img class="ro-1 is-rotating" 
       draggable="false" 
       src="http://placekitten.com/101"
       data-rotate-next=".ro-2">
  <img class="ro-2 is-rotating" 
       draggable="false" 
       src="http://placekitten.com/102"
       data-rotate-next=".ro-1">
</div>
```

Comment: I actually really like that decoupling article. Some of this I'm doing, as its what I've always done, and some I might implement, and some seems to be overkill -- but it is an interesting perspective.