# Inline event handler practice javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I am reading about Events on the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), here it talks about "Inline events handlers" these should not be used and are considered a bad practice.

e.g.

```
<button onclick="bgChange()">Press me</button>
```

However, in frameworks such as Angular we do something like:

```
<my-component (click)="onClick($event)"></my-component>
```

Is this not contradicting to what bad practice is considerd by Mozilla in this case?

If this question needs to be asked in another section, please do let me know.

Comment: They are totally different things.

Comment: > If this question needs to be asked in another section, please do let me know.

Which question? You did not ask any

Comment: @smnbbrv There is a question, just no question mark.

Comment: The angular version is a template, so the angular engine will replace that syntax with proper event handlers, while in the vanilla version the handler stays inline. Some of the reasons why it's considered a bad practice is seperation of concerns, eg html and javascript should not be in the same file. It also makes it more difficult to update later on if you have to look at the HTML source as well to figure out what happens where. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-is-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html  they have more arguments.

Comment: @shilly that sounds like a good answer..

Comment: makes sense  thank you @Shilly

Comment: question mark added :p @smnbbrv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question of "separation of concerns", and your component is generally separated into a file, which then contains the "control" of that component.

Angular directives are basically an idea that builds upon this in your templates.

In-lining it into the html without such a system of functionality (like angular) is akin to writing your entire html templates in your javascript --- bad, unless you have a system that is helping you do that.

Basically, without angular you should "keep your javascript in your javascript" and your "html in your html".

Read further about MVC and separation of concerns at

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-javascript-applications/9781491950289/ch05.html

> Angular’s controllers might remind you a lot of models from other MVC
>   implementations, if you’re a follower of the “fat models, skinny
>   controllers” approach.