# Passing an object variable through html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to pass an object through HTML but am getting the

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

error. I am still learning JavaScript DOM and would appreciate any help.

```
data = getdata(); //retreive my data
var mtable = document.createElement("table"); //create table element via javascript
mtable.innerHTML += "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Modify</th></tr>";
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var ins = createEle("tr");
    ins.innerHTML = "<td>" + data[i]['name'] + "</td>";
    ins.innerHTML += "<td><button id=" + data[i]['tid'] + " onclick=make_modifytourney2(this.id," + data[i] + ")>Modify</button></td></tr>";
    mtable.appendChild(ins);
}
```

I am then appending `mtable` to the document. `data[i]` is an array object which I want to pass via this code but it is not working. I know that I can use `tid` to retrieve again this data but I'd rather not since the data is already there.

Edit: My createEle

```
function createEle(ele, css) {
var nn = document.createElement(ele);
nn.setAttribute("class", css);
return nn;
}
```

a simple helper
Edit 2
My array data will be something like this

```
  data=[(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0
  :
  {name: "T1", tid: 1, fdate: "2018-07-11", tdate: "2018-07-26", category: "mens", …}
  1
  :
  {name: "T2", tid: 2, fdate: "2018-07-20", tdate: "2018-07-26", category: "womens", …}
  2
  :
  {name: "nart", tid: 3, fdate: "0001-01-01", tdate: "0001-01-01", category: "1", …}
  3
  :
  {name: "xyz", tid: 4, fdate: "0001-01-01", tdate: "0222-02-01", category: "23", …}]
```

Comment: You need a semi-colon after this line: `ins.innerHTML = "<td>" + data[i]['name'] + "</td>"`. Also, you may benefit from familiarizing with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.)

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` or `oninput` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_don't_use_these) or a similar functionality provided by the library of framework you use instead. `data[i]` is definitely not properly quoted. The missing `;` is _not_ the issue, as ASI takes care of that.

Comment: the semi colon went missing in code cleanup , sorry

Comment: I tested your code. The error happens when clicking on the modify button. Can you confirm?

Comment: You may consider looking at the following page regarding using JavaScript to add a table to HTML https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Comment: yeah, when i click on modify i get the error

Comment: thanks a lot @daddygames never knew something like was there

Comment: To clarify, the actual issue is the improper nested quoting of the arguments in `"<td><button id=" + data[i]['tid'] + " onclick=make_modifytourney2(this.id," + data[i] + ")>Modify</button></td></tr>"`. `" + data[i] + "` should be `'" + data[i] + "'` or something similar, but a far better solution would be to use `addEventListener`, since `data[i]` wouldn’t need to be stringified, then eval’d again.

Comment: @NiteyaShah I wouldn’t recommend W3Schools. Use [MDN’s `insertRow` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) instead.

Comment: the single quotes didn't work,i will try the addEventListener() after i read about it

Comment: is there some way i can refer to the function without executing it because then all my problems will be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs when clicking the Modify button you generated.

Mainly because you declared this instruction in your `onclick` attribute with this :

```
make_modifytourney2(this.id," + data[i] + ")
```

which generates the following HTML code :

```
<button id="undefined" onclick="make_modifytourney2(this.id,[object" object])>Modify</button>
```

And now you have some cut JavaScript code in your onclick attribute.

I don't know if it's a typo or not, but anyway, if you want get rid of that error, you need to :

- use escaped double quotes to encapsulate the onclick attribute instruction
- use espaced single quotes to encapsulte the parameters of your function call

Your code will be :

```
ins.innerHTML += "<td><button id=" + data[i]['tid'] + " onclick=\"make_modifytourney2(this.id,'" + data[i] + "')\">Modify</button></td></tr>";
```

```js
function getdata() { 
  return [{name : "John"}, {name : "Jack"}];
}

function createEle(ele, css) {
  var nn = document.createElement(ele);
  nn.setAttribute("class", css);
  return nn;
}

function make_modifytourney2(param1, param2) {
  console.log(`Clicked Modify with params : ${param1}, ${param2}`);
}

var data = getdata(); //retreive my data
var mtable = document.createElement("table"); //create table element via javascript
mtable.innerHTML += "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Modify</th></tr>";
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var ins = createEle("tr");
  ins.innerHTML = "<td>" + data[i]['name'] + "</td>"
  ins.innerHTML += "<td><button id=" + data[i]['tid'] + " onclick=\"make_modifytourney2(this.id,'" + data[i] + "')\">Modify</button></td></tr>";
  mtable.appendChild(ins);
}
document.body.appendChild(mtable);
```

Now this is kind of messy because of the way you generate your element. It would rather suggest you use DOM elements as JavaScript object and use an event listener.

Here's what it would look like :

```js
function getdata() {
  // dummy object with a tid and a name field 
  return [{
    tid: '1',
    name: "John"
  }, {
    tid: '2',
    name: "Jack"
  }];
}

function createEle(ele, css) {
  var nn = document.createElement(ele);
  nn.setAttribute("class", css);
  return nn;
}

// function that creates a TD element with a child 
function createTd(child) {
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.appendChild(child);
  return td;
}

// function that creates a modify button based on your data object 
function createModifyButton(data) {
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = data.tid;
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // use whatever parameter you need from the data object : 
    make_modifytourney2(data.tid, data.name);
  });
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Modify"));
  return button;
}

function make_modifytourney2(param1, param2) {
  console.log(`Clicked Modify with params : ${param1}, ${param2}`);
}

// local variables 
var data, mtable, i, ins, row1, row2;

data = getdata(); //retreive my data
mtable = document.createElement("table"); //create table element via javascript
mtable.innerHTML += "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Modify</th></tr>";
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  ins = createEle("tr");
  // creating tds and appending them : 
  row1 = createTd(document.createTextNode(data[i]['name']));
  ins.appendChild(row1);
  row2 = createTd(createModifyButton(data[i]));
  ins.appendChild(row2);

  mtable.appendChild(ins);
}
document.body.appendChild(mtable);
```

Comment: I actually did this before but what is happening is that the function is getting executed for every value of i ,i.e i am getting a clicked Modify for every sub-element in data

Comment: @NiteyaShah I updated my answer with another snippet using DOM elements as JavaScript objects and an event listener.

Comment: i believe that the odd execution is because every time my code refers to it in onclick it also executes it but im not sure

Answer (score 0):

This error comes generally when you forget a bracket or parenthesis (often the two at the same time)
Check if everything is closed correctly. 
If you don't find anything, check on an online parser, you will see the problem just by identing :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: While this suggestion is certainly helpful, it is not an *answer*. In the future, consider posting this as a *comment* instead :)

Comment: Would you be able to paste your code in a [CodePen](http://www.codepen.io/) or a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can try it out?