# In-line javascript: understanding what counts as in-line and what doesn't for a better CSP

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

At the very basic level, I understand that in-line javascript is the following:

```
<script>prompt()</script>
```

And this does not count as in-line javascript:

```
<script src="foo.com/bar.js"></script>
```

However, there's also other places where javascript can live, such as:

```
<button onclick="prompt()">
<form onsubmit="prompt()">
<img onerror="prompt()">
<style>{something "property":"javascript:prompt()"}</style>
```

Do all the other places that javascript live also count as in-line javascript?

What is the work-around for this? [Inline Event handlers are also a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-is-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html?noredirect=1&lq=1)

According to [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991), I would have to register event handlers before the closing body. Eg. I would assign each element on the page a specific ID, and AddEventListener on each element.

To make sure that I understand the idea, suppose I have a form - before the end of the body, I would include a javascript file that adds an event listener, so that my HTML would look like this:

```
<body>
<form id="theForm" name="theForm" method="POST"></form>
<script src="eventlisteners.js"></script>
</body>
```

And eventlisteners.js would like this:

```
var frm = document.getElementById("theForm");
frm.addEventListener('submit', console.log('foo'))
```

Is this correct? Is it also correct to say that **every HTML inline event listener has a corresponding addEventListener argument?**

Comment: You can assign event listeners to elements based on class names as well using `document.getElementsByClassName()`, which may be more suitable in some cases rather than doing this for each ID.

Comment: "*I would have to register event handlers before the closing body*" - no, you can register them from anywhere at any time (assuming that the DOM element exists already, you can't select it before it got parsed). Putting a `<script>` right in front of the `</body>` tag is just the easiest solution.

Comment: "*every HTML inline event listener has a corresponding addEventListener argument?*" - not exactly, inline event listeners correspond to the [old `element.onclick = listener` model](https://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)