# Do a function if specific word is submitted in textbox

Tags: javascript

how would I get a textbox perform a function if a specific word is submitted. I have a robot that jumps on mousedown and I want it to jump if I write jump or write move in the textbox it does the move function. I tried few things but couldnt get it to work

Heres the code

```
 <form id="formDiv" action="" >
Command the robot!: <input type="text" size="50" onkeydown="keyCode(event)"> 



</form> 
    <div id="canvasDiv" width="500" height="10"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="robotti.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        prepareCanvas(document.getElementById("canvasDiv"), 500, 500);

        document.getElementById("canvasDiv").onmousedown = function() { 
            jump(); }

            //document.getElementById("canvasDiv").onkeypress = function() { 
            //move(); }

            document.getElementById("canvasDiv").window.onkeypress = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 41) {
      move();
   }
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -:

```
var text = getElementById("canvasDiv").value;
if(text.includes("move") || text.includes("jump")){
    jump();
    getElementById("canvasDiv").value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use onkeyup instead of onkeydown

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<input type="text" id="canvasDiv" onkeyup="keyCode()" value="">


<script>
function keyCode(e) {
 var text = (document.getElementById("canvasDiv").value).toLowerCase();
 if(text  == 'jump' || text == 'move'){
  //call jump function here
    alert("jump");
 }
 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use HTML attributes like `onkeydown` etc. Use an [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. Register one on your input field, grab its value and check (either via [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) or [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)) what the user entered. According to the user's input, execute your functions.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  switch (this.value) {
    case 'move':
      console.log('move!'); // Your actual function here
      this.value = ''; // Reset value
      break;
    case 'jump':
      console.log('jump!'); // Your actual function here
      this.value = '' // Reset value
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
Command the robot!: <input type="text" size="50">
```

---

Further reading:

[Why is inline event handler attributes a bad idea in modern semantic HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-is-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html)

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)