# How to remove specific attribute from all elements inside div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How to remove `style` attributes from all elements (children) inside the `<div class="parent">`?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var divsname = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("parent"));
  divsname.forEach(function(div) {
    divs.removeAttribute("style");
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="parent" name="parentone">
    <div id="childone" style="height:10px">
      <div id="childtwo" style="background-color:red"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent" name="parenttwo">
    <div id="childthree" style="height:10px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_—_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the *descendants* of `.parent`, not the elements with the class `parent`. It’s not quite clear whether you only want the [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) or all [descendants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). Use the right combinator for your purpose.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".parent *") // descendants
document.querySelectorAll(".parent > *") // children
```

Then, you can replace [`*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) by [`[style]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select only elements that actually have a `style` attribute.

Instead of `Array.prototype.slice.call`, use the more modern [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Finally, just remove the attributes using `forEach` (and an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)).

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".parent [style]"))
  .forEach((elem) => elem.removeAttribute("style"));
```