# JavaScript button that changes the value in the checkbox field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a button that when clicked replaces the value in the field true false. If we click the first time the field becomes true, if the second time the field becomes false. But I still can't get the results. The field only changes true.

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

<button onclick="check()">Check Checkbox</button>

<script>
  function check() {
    var value = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    if (value = "false") {
      document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you replace the `<button>` with a `<label>` (which has its `for`/`htmlFor` attribute set to the `id` of the `<input>`) then you get this behaviour for free. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7sLh1n9z/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid [inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html) ("onclick"). You can simplify this using:

```js
const checkUncheck = () => {
  const cb = document.querySelector("#myCheck");
  cb.checked = !cb.checked;
};

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", checkUncheck);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" disabled>
<button>check/uncheck</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the `checked` attribute of your checkbox is true or false.

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

<button onclick="check()">Check Checkbox</button>

<script>
  function check() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    if (checkbox.checked !== true) {
      checkbox.checked = true;
    } else {
      checkbox.checked = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Also, you can re-use the `checkbox` variable.