# problem with document querySelector implementation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding this piece of code to attach an `ID` to a class (`li.search`) inside a `li` element.

```
document.querySelector('li.search').id = 'ControlOverlay';
```

It works on some of my sites, but on a recent installation, it doesn't attach the `ID` to the `class`.

My implentation works when I test it on `w3schools.com`, but not on my site...

Any ideas on what maybe wrong?

Am'I forgetting to reference any library?

Here's my implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

#overlays {position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:0;background:rgba(110, 173, 238,.9);}
.standby2 {display:none;}
ul {list-style:none;}
</style>
<body>

<ul class="menu">
                <li class="search"><a aria-label="Open" href="#"><span class="gp-icon icon-search"><svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" aria-hidden="true" role="img" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1em" height="1em">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M208 48c-88.366 0-160 71.634-160 160s71.634 160 160 160 160-71.634 160-160S296.366 48 208 48zM0 208C0 93.125 93.125 0 208 0s208 93.125 208 208c0 48.741-16.765 93.566-44.843 129.024l133.826 134.018c9.366 9.379 9.355 24.575-.025 33.941-9.379 9.366-24.575 9.355-33.941-.025L337.238 370.987C301.747 399.167 256.839 416 208 416 93.125 416 0 322.875 0 208z"></path>
                    </svg><svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" aria-hidden="true" role="img" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1em" height="1em">
                        <path d="M71.029 71.029c9.373-9.372 24.569-9.372 33.942 0L256 222.059l151.029-151.03c9.373-9.372 24.569-9.372 33.942 0 9.372 9.373 9.372 24.569 0 33.942L289.941 256l151.03 151.029c9.372 9.373 9.372 24.569 0 33.942-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0L256 289.941l-151.029 151.03c-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0-9.372-9.373-9.372-24.569 0-33.942L222.059 256 71.029 104.971c-9.372-9.373-9.372-24.569 0-33.942z"></path>
                    </svg></span></a></li>          </ul>

<script>

document.querySelector('li.search').id = 'ControlOverlay';
document.getElementById("ControlOverlay").setAttribute("onclick", "ShowOverlay();");
function ShowOverlay(){document.getElementById("overlays").classList.toggle("standby2")}

</script>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ad5kqo4g/)

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн on the demos, it work's! Not on my implementation...

Comment: maybe you can share your implementation

Comment: It can be one of a billion things wrong, hard to randomly guess. Like playing darts blindfolded. Might get a bullseye or might hit someone in the rear.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, it’s not possible to tell what’s wrong. The code you’ve shown either throws an error if no `<li class="search">` is found, or assigns the ID `"ControlOverlay"` to the first `<li class="search">` in your DOM. It does _not_ attach IDs to classes, as that makes no sense; `li.search` is a selector, _not_ a class; and the `search` class is _on_ your `<li>`, _not inside_ it.

Comment: Ok, which means that code is working fine. There must be some issue with setup on your end, which is very hard for us to debug as we don't have any access to your site. You have to check the audit logs and stuff to figure out the issue.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `deferred` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: Oops, I meant _`defer` attribute_ in my previous comment. Also, I’d recommend you to abandon W3Schools and go with a more reputable learning resource like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/) instead.

Comment: @Hexception Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @bpy Your code is working. Inspect the elements on your page. You’ll see a `<li id="ControlSearchOverlay" class="search-item" onclick="ShowHideOverlay();">` in there. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_—_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: Why do you have to add an id to add an event handler? You already have a reference to the element.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is on `document.getElementById("overlay")`

You don't have an element with the id `overlay` in your HTML.

I would also edit

```js
document.getElementById("ControlSearchOverlay").setAttribute("onclick", "ShowHideOverlay();");
function ShowHideOverlay(){
    document.getElementById("overlay").classList.toggle("standby")
}
```

to:

```js
document.getElementById("ControlSearchOverlay").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").classList.toggle("standby")
}
```

as user4642212 mentioned it would be good to rather use addEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

```js
document.getElementById("ControlSearchOverlay").addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").classList.toggle("standby")
})
```

Comment: The bottom half of the answer is neither true nor good advice. Use `addEventListener`, not the `onclick` property. No, you do not have to declare the function beforehand.

Comment: addEventListener is only usefull if you have more then one listener. or you are creating a libary

Comment: but i can add it too

Comment: sorry @hexception... I didn't put the `overlay` `div` on the code. The question is updated. Thanks!

Comment: @Hexception Or event delegation. Or when you need to control the bubbling or capturing behavior. Or if you want to easily control that your event listener should only fire once. Or if you just want to write future-proof, maintainable code.

Comment: So yes I agree with you but I would just improve the setAttribute

Comment: @bpy is your problem solved or you just missed the div by asking the question?

Comment: @Hexception still unsolved. Missed the `div` when asking...

Comment: now you are calling ShowOverlay(); and there is only a function called ShowHideOverlay

Comment: @bpy Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser yourself, then edit your question with a _clear_ problem description.

Comment: The program is still calling ShowOverlay but only a function called ShowHideOverlay exists

Comment: @Hexception there's no more `ShowHideOverlay` in my `code` example. Please check my `fiddle` or `code` example

Comment: document.getElementById("ControlOverlay").setAttribute("onclick", "ShowOverlay();");
function ShowHideOverlay(){document.getElementById("overlays").classList.toggle("standby2")}

Comment: @bpy So what is your _actual_ problem now? Have you read any of the error messages in the console?

Comment: If you dont see any error message you have to TRIGGER it by clicking on your search item