# enable and disable checkbox based on toggle of Custom toggle Switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a custom toggle switch, so when I toogle it to ON, it should display the checkboxes in list item and on turning OFF the toggle, it should hide checkboxes in list item. How can I achieve this?

**Toggle switch**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" checked>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"><h>TOGGLE</h> 
    </label>
</div>
```

**Checkbox**

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox">first</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">second</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with a [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event function to `show` and `hide` your checkboxes `UL` based on `toggle` switch.

Initially, set your `checkboxes` to display: none and then in `JS` check if the toggle is switched `ON` by using [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked) attribute and if toggle is OFF set the checkboxes to none again to `hide` them

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
let getSwitch = document.querySelector('#customSwitch1') //get switch

let getCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheckBoxes') //get checkboxes UL

getSwitch.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  getCheckboxes.forEach(function(o) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      o.style.display = 'inline-block'
    } else {
      o.style.display = 'none'
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.myCheckBoxes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">
    <h>TOGGLE</h>
  </label>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><input class="myCheckBoxes" type="checkbox">first</li>
  <li><input class="myCheckBoxes" type="checkbox">second</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want li items to be displayed all the time.Only the checkboxes should be shown and hidden

Comment: @kavya See my updated answer. working as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the help..Can I have the same with Check and uncheck checkbox with toggle button..The checkbox should be visible all the time and check and uncheck should be based on toggle button

Comment: @kavya Thats feels like a seperate question to ask as it is totally different thing you are asking - According to stackoverflow this need to be asked in different thread. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using `onchange` event as shown below:

```js
function myFunction() {
   var chks = document.querySelectorAll("#myDIV input[type='checkbox']");
   for(var i=0;i<chks.length;i++) {
    if (chks[i].style.display === "none") {
     chks[i].style.display = "inline";
    } else {
    chks[i].style.display = "none";
 }
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" checked onchange="myFunction()">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"><h>TOGGLE</h> 
    </label>
</div>
<div id="myDIV">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox">first</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">second</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do **not** use recemened using **inline event handler** - its a bad idea - Read this => [Why are inline event handler attributes a bad idea in modern semantic HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html)

Answer (score 1):

This could possibly be achieved with plain CSS too

```css
.trigger {
  display: none;
}
#customSwitch1:checked + .trigger {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"><h>TOGGLE</h></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" checked>
<div class="trigger">
<ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox">first</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox">second</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[Check this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ycoxhv/)

Answer (score 0):

**NB: *The code can be refactored***..Try this implementation.

```js
document.getElementById("customSwitch1").addEventListener("click", toggle)
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let isChecked = document.getElementById("customSwitch1").checked
  if (isChecked) {
    document.getElementById("ul_checkboxes").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ul_checkboxes").style.display = "none";

  }
});

function toggle(e) {
  let isChecked = e.target.checked
  if (isChecked) {
    document.getElementById("ul_checkboxes").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ul_checkboxes").style.display = "none";

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" checked>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"><h>TOGGLE</h> 
     </label>
</div>
Checkbox

<ul id="ul_checkboxes">
  <li><input type="checkbox">first</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">second</li>
</ul>
```