# The onsubmit event handler javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. When I clicked the submit button nothing happens, even when I filled out the username and password with numbers (I don't want the username and password contains any number so I did make the condition for it), there is no alert display. I do not know where the problem comes from? Can you guys help me with this

Note: the reset function works fine

```js
function validateInput() {
  var firstName = document.forms["sign_up"]["firstName"];
  var lastName = document.forms["sign_up"]["lastName"];
  var email = document.forms["sign_up"]["email"];
  var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (firstName.value !== '' || lastName.value !== '' || email.value !== '') {
    if (firstName.value.match(reg) && lastName.value.match(reg)) {
      alert("Form is submitted");
      // return true;
      return false; // for the demo, so it doesn't submit
    } else {
      if (firstName.value.match(reg) === false) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Numbers are not allowed in username";
        return false;
      } else if (lastName.value.match(reg) === false) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Numbers are not allowed in password";
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("last").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<form id="sign_up" onsubmit="return validateInput()">
  <p id="error"></p>
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" value="" placeholder="Enter your first name">
  <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" value="" placeholder="Enter your last name">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Enter your email">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="reset();">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: change ai by name -> `name="firstName"`

Comment: Any errors in your console (I bet there are)?

Comment: I think @MisterJojo means to change `id` to `name`. I would say to just add `name` attributes and keep the `id` ones as well

Comment: Without `name` attributes, your form elements won't submit. Nor will you be able to reference them by `document.forms["sign_up"]["firstName"]` (your `<form>` needs a name for that one too).

Comment: I just checked and no problem in the console

Comment: Ran the same piece of code and the reset function does not have a closing parenthesis. Just provided that and the alert began to show up.

Comment: Your function has an undefined return path. You should add `return false` at the end

Comment: I put name attributes for the input already but the problem still there

Comment: But `validateInput` does nothing. I mean you can see effect of `reset`, but not of `validateInput`. Try to put `console.log("Hello")` at first line inside the function.

Comment: The console display Hello when I clicked submit but I do not know why it does not work for the others?

Comment: @BeefNoodle not sure if you have seen my answer below - all working for you and code fixed up.

Comment: you didn't test if all inputs are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to **avoid** to [inline event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html) as they are not rec-emended at all. Also to reset form values you can simply use [reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method on the form.

Also, do not use `innerHTML` just to set the text of your error. You can use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead which is better fit in your example.

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with `submit` event to check for `validation` on your `firstname` and `lastname`.

I have fixed your `code` and its all working as expected.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
let form = document.getElementById("sign_up")
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName")
var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName")
var email = document.getElementById("email")
var reset = document.getElementById("clearValues")
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (firstName.value != '' || lastName.value != '' || email.value != '') {
    if (firstName.value.match(reg) && lastName.value.match(reg)) {
      alert("Form is submitted");
    } else if (!firstName.value.match(reg)) {
      document.getElementById("error").textContent = "Numbers are not allowed in username";
    } else if (!lastName.value.match(reg)) {
      document.getElementById("error").textContent = "Numbers are not allowed in password";
    }
  }
})

reset.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.getElementById("sign_up").reset();
})
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="sign_up" action="#">
    <p id="error"></p>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" value="" placeholder="Enter your first name">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" value="" placeholder="Enter your last name">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Enter your email">
    <button type="submit">
       Submit
     </button>
    <button type="button" id="clearValues" onclick="reset();">
       Cancel
     </button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Pattern` attribute in input for validation like below

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" value="" pattern="[^0-9]*" title="Numbers are not allowed" placeholder="Enter your first name">
```

for more references: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

And for reset functionality use `reset`

```
<input type="reset" value="reset">
```

It's better than create a special function for it and it saves your number of lines:-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return a function in onsubmit event. This should work fine.

```
 <form id="sign_up" onsubmit="validateInput()">
```

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Comment: This is incorrect. See these two examples; [without return](https://jsfiddle.net/rjb3k4us/) vs [with return](https://jsfiddle.net/rjb3k4us/1/)