# How to set the content of an alert in javascript as per the element which is clicked?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I'm trying to return the text of this

into an alert. Why is this returning 'undefined'?

```js
function print()
{
  alert(this.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p id="G1" onclick='print()'>Gourc'hemonnoù!</p>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_—_dont_use_these) instead. And please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser, e.g. `console.log(this)` to figure out what `this` is.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this` inside the `function`, it means "this function". What you have to do is to pass the element in `<p id="G1" onclick='print(this)'` `this` in here means current element. Then inside your function you can use the element you passes.

```js
function print(element)
{
  alert(element.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p id="G1" onclick='print(this)'>Gourc'hemonnoù!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function print()
{
  alert(document.getElementById('G1').innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p id="G1" onclick='print()'>Gourc'hemonnoù!</p>
```