# Inserting script in createElement Method

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make new element using `createElement` method. But in this case I want `id` attribute should change as variable changes while adding Dynamic Input using Button.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Here, I'm using `\n` for new line for formating input in `createElement` method.

Below code was working If I remove `script` tag. But in this case I want `script` tag for using [select2](https://select2.org/).

```js
var personCount = 1;

function addNewInput(divName){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = '<select style="width: 100%" id="person'+ (personCount + 1) +'"StateInput" ></select>\n\
                        <script>\n\
                          $('#person'+ (personCount + 1) +'"StateInput').select2({\n\
                              ajax: {\n\
                                url: 'url/for/state',\n\
                                dataType: 'json'\n\
                              }\n\
                            });\n\
                        </script>';
  
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    count++;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  

    <select style="width: 100%" id="person1StateInput" ></select>
    <script>
      $('#Test1A').select2({
          ajax: {
            url: 'url/state',
            dataType: 'json'
          }
        });
    </script>

<div id="add"></div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addNewInput('add');">Add Peaky Blinder</button>
```

The code will explain the problem better rather than a description

Comment: Apart from the syntax error due to incorrect quoting, and potentially from the fact that `</script>` terminates the script, inserting a script in `innerHTML` will not work. Why not simply call a function with the JS code?

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_—_dont_use_these) or jQuery’s [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: This is not the right approach. If you intend to add new `select` menus (&other html) dynamically you might be better assigning an event handler to the parent node ( this node that you add the new content to ) and use `event delegation` to find what the event was, what triggered it and then react accordingly. Certainly no need to add a new function for each select menu

Comment: What do you do with the ajax response?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius This is just example for using script in `innerHTML`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Can help with Syntax Error using script in `createElement` method.

Comment: ok so the ajax call is not important? As for the error message - why not just insert a new HTML element from scratch rather than a string?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, Yes that AJAX is not important. Yes inserting new  HTML is required but inserting `script` is required.

Comment: @Maqsud _“inserting `script` is required”_ — No, it is not, because this will never work. Again, why can’t you just put that script code in a function and call it?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Can you show me the solution to this problem.

Comment: @Maqsud Please see a [tutorial on how to declare and use functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unclear what the real objective ultimately is but you said you need to insert new HTML elements and new scripts( why though ? ) ~ you can use `createElement` to create all of these things, including new scripts. The following is loosely based upon the code you provided - a new Select will be created in the `#add` div and  anew script element will also be added - though it is of limited use "as-is"

```js
var personCount = 1;

const addPeakyBlinder=function(divName){
  let oSelect=document.createElement('select');
    oSelect.id='person'+personCount;
    oSelect.style.width='100%';
    /* below for demo only */
    oSelect.appendChild(new Option('apple','apple'));
    oSelect.appendChild(new Option('banana','banana'));
    oSelect.appendChild(new Option('peach','peach'));

  let oScript=document.createElement('script');
    oScript.textContent=`
      console.log('loaded');
    `;

  let oDiv=document.createElement('div');   
    oDiv.appendChild(oSelect);
    oDiv.appendChild(oScript)



  document.getElementById( divName ).appendChild( oDiv );
  personCount++;
}


document.getElementById( 'add' ).addEventListener('change',e=>{
  console.info( 'Do interesting things.. now we know the origin for the request and the value: %s %s %s %s', e.type, e.target, e.target.value, e.target.id )
});
```

```html
<div id="add"></div>
<button onclick="addPeakyBlinder('add');">Add Peaky Blinder</button>
```

Comment: I want to have a different `id` attribute as per the value of count.

Answer (score 1):

I just modified the answer of @ProfessorAbronsius which is the exact solution I wanted.

```js
var personCount = 1;

const addPeakyBlinder=function(divName){
  let oSelect=document.createElement('select');
    oSelect.style.width='100%';
    oSelect.setAttribute("id", "Test"+ (personCount + 1) +"A");

  let oScript=document.createElement('script');
    oScript.textContent=`
       $("#Test`+ (personCount + 1) +`A").select2({\n\
          ajax: {\n\
            url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',\n\
            dataType: 'json'\n\
          }\n\
        });\n\
    `;

  let oDiv=document.createElement('div');   
    oDiv.appendChild(oSelect);
    oDiv.appendChild(oScript)

personCount++

  document.getElementById( divName ).appendChild( oDiv );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  

    <select style="width: 100%" id="Test1A" ></select>
    <script>
      $('#Test1A').select2({
          ajax: {
            url: 'url/state',
            dataType: 'json'
          }
        });
    </script>

<div id="add"></div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addPeakyBlinder('add');">Add Peaky Blinder</button>
```