# What is the returned value of a clicked <button>?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, event-handling

I want to get the returned value of a clicked button, and then use it to make an `if` statement. All the answers that I read here about people trying to do that are either very old using old script that doesn't work anymore, or not the same case.

```js
function remove() {
  if (document.getElementById("removing").value == true) {

    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
<button id="removing" onclick="remove()">Remove a word</button>
```

I have tried using the `value` property, and `onclick`, but non of them equal true when the button is clicked.

I tried using `alert` to display the `value`, but it displays nothing.

Does clicking a button actually returns a value, and if so, what is it?

Comment: No, clicking a button does not return a value. In general, **events** don't "return" any value. They just happen and you can register event handlers to be executed when they happen. The fact that `remove` is executed means that the button was clicked.

Comment: I see. So, how do I do that? How do I use an executed event in an if statement?

Comment: I don't understand why you need an `if` statement? Where do you want to know that the button was clicked? Please provide more context. In your example, the fact that `remove` is called already means that the button is clicked.

Comment: @FelixKling ... Since one could invoke such a handler function from anywhere just like this ... `remove()` ... I assume the OP just wants to be sure about the handler being invoked from within an event handling process.

Comment: @PeterSeliger: Possibly. But it can only be helpful for the OP to clarify :)

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded yet. I read all the answers here, but I am trying to assimilate and make sense of a lot of information right now. I am testing and experimenting a whole bunch of stuff right now. Given that I'm very new to JS, some of the stuff that I keep seeing don't make sense to me, and I am trying to make sense of it, and formulate some key questions so I can ask you guys while I have the opportunity. Please give me some time before I can formulate my questions in a more proper way.

Comment: Hey. So, I don't have any other additional questions to my original question, but I do want to ask you guys about something a bit unrelated. When you convert a string into an array, and then use splice to remove array items from it by clicking a button, but instead of setting the exact item to be removed, you use counter++ instead, now, why is it that, if I remove an item and then replace it with another one, the counter incrementation works as expected. For each occurrence it increases with 1, but if I choose not to replace an item, just remove it, the incrementation increases with 2. Why?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle for demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/z8gu4bm2/

Comment: @Ihatecontrolfreaks ... the additional question most probably will not be answered unless it was ask as (or in a) separate thread.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I thought it was a simple 1 sentence answer, that's why I didn't want to make a new thread for it, but it's fine. No worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#properties)s are handled by an [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)'s [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback).

Thus such a handler function, if triggered by an event and forwarded by an event listener's `handleEvent` method, always will be invoked with an event object as this function's single argument.

All information related to this event are carried by the event itself. Its properties can be read and some even can be written/changed.

It is obvious from the provided example that the OP wants to assure that an event handler has been triggered by just a specific html element. Thus any valid approach just needs to look into the event's [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property ...

```js
// the way the OP might want to handle the problem.
function handleRemoveWord(evt) {
  const elmNode = evt.currentTarget;

  // make sure the handler was
  // triggered by the intended element ...
  // ... here by comparing node properties.
  if (
    (elmNode.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'BUTTON')
    && (elmNode.id === 'remove')
  ) {
    document
      .getElementById('test')
      .style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}

// another way the OP might want to handle the problem.
function handleRemoveAnotherWord(evt) {

  // `this` referres to the element which got
  // bound to the handler via `addEventListener`.
  const targetNode = this;

  // make sure the handler was
  // triggered by the intended element ...
  // ... here by comparing node references.
  if (targetNode === evt.currentTarget) {
    document
      .getElementById('test')
      .style.backgroundColor = 'cyan';
  }
}

// an alternative way of solving the problem
// of always being assured about the correct
// element having triggering the event handling.
function handleRestoreWordWithBoundContext(evt) {
  const context = this;
  const { elmTest, elmRestore } = context;

  // make sure the handler was
  // triggered by the intended element ...
  // ... here by comparing node references.
  if (elmRestore === evt.currentTarget) {

    elmTest.style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}


function initialize() {
  // the way(s) the OP might want to handle the problem.
  document
    .getElementById('remove')
    .addEventListener('click', handleRemoveWord);

  document
    .querySelector('#removeAnother')
    .addEventListener('click', handleRemoveAnotherWord);

  // an alternative way of soving the problem
  // of always being assured about the correct
  // element having triggering the event handling.
  const elmTest = document.querySelector('#test');
  const elmRestore = document.querySelector('#restore');

  elmRestore.addEventListener(
    'click',
    handleRestoreWordWithBoundContext.bind({
      elmTest, 
      elmRestore,
    })
  );
}
initialize();
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>

<button id="remove">Remove a word</button>
<button id="removeAnother">Remove another word</button>
<button id="restore">Restore a word</button>
```

As one might have noticed, the example features a third button with yet another way of implementing an event handler. This additional handler assumes its `this` context to carry additional information. This is possible by invoking [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/bind) on this handler function and providing exactly the information one wants to be present as the event handlers `this` context. Every time this function specific method is invoked it creates another function which does have access to the bound information via the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching Javascript event handlers always returns true, even if it returns false, which we all know is used to prevent default behaviour of an event. We don't usually use the return values of Event handlers or even return anything for that matter.

In your case, I think you're trying to acess the value of the **currentTarget** element(the button 'removing' in your case). For this you can use the event object, which gets passed on as parameter to your event handler.

**event.currentTarget** is a way of referencing the element on which an event is being dispatched(triggered) on. It's just like using 'this' inside the event handler, except it also works on arrow functions.

So do something like this:

```
function remove(event) {
  let button = event.currentTarget;
  if (buttton.value) {
   document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor ="red";
  }
}
```

and in HTML,

```
<div id="test">test</div>
<button id="removing" onclick="remove(event)">Remove a word</button>
```

Notice I've used remove(*event*).

**Edit Based on comment below**:
Using onclick will require you to create you a global 'remove' function.
If you do, '...onclick="remove(event)" what it basically does is creates the function below, a wrapper basically:

```
// In the global scope
[reference element].onclick = ()  => {
  remove(event);
}
```

So you must have a global 'remove' function. So this won't work in modules cause each modules have their own top level scope. And you're gonna wanna have to use modules if you plan to work on sophisticated projects.

**NOTE Using inline 'onclick' attributes in html has following disadvantages on heavy requests from a comment below**:

-separation of concern : You usually don't want to mix up your UI logic(what happens on clicking a button) with presentation. You want a clear split between content, style and script.

-only one handler can be assigned using onclick.

-if an event is specified inline, the JS is specified as a string (attribute values are always strings) and evaluated when the event fires.(extra wrapper code builds internally).

-as I've mentioned before, you are faced with having to reference named functions. This is not ideal and has implications on the function needing to be global which will really bite you back when you use modules.

In short, handle events centrally via the dedicated addEventListener API.

Comment: Please do not use ´event´ as global *out of the blue* variable as it is practiced by the given examples inline style ... `<button ... onclick="remove(event)">` ... What one really want is a proper initializing/registering of the `remove` event handler via `[buttonReference].addEventListener('click', remove)`. Please change your code accordingly and even try making it an executable snippet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterSeliger what do you think of the edit above. I'm new to programming and could really use opinion in general. Thanks in advance.

Comment: but isn't event always available like that. It's not like we need to import it from somewhere is it? Or am I missing something? Because you're soooooo OP.

Comment: Making use of inline event handling and the global `event` object is considered harmful and thus bad practice.

Comment: @Peter Seliger care to explain as to why it is considered harmful.

Comment: The first highest ranked answers of ... [Why are inline event handler attributes a bad idea ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html) ... in addition [Inline event handlers — don't use these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) ... and [Disadvantages of using HTML event handler attributes](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/handling-events-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply change background color onClick of button as:

```js
function remove() {
  document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
<button id="removing" onclick="remove()">Remove a word</button>
```

Comment: I think what the OP tries to tackle is not the above shown basic kind of event handling. The OP is looking for an approach which assures a certain element being the trigger of an event or the event's current target.