# Count the number of checkbox and amount in table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a trouble on how can I count total check in table checkbox and total all amount on amount column based of what been checked in checkbox field.I'm new in javascript and html. It would be great if anyone can help me with this problem, thanks in advance!

```js
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
 }
 }
```

```html
<table class="table" name="table" id="table">
        <thead>
          <tr >
          <th></th>
          <th ><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /></th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Another value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
            <td>Jessica</td>
            <td>5200</td>
            <td>somethingnew</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]" ></td>
            <td>Jessica</td>
            <td>800</td>
            <td>Somevalue</td>
          </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
          Number of checkbox = <p id="total_checked"></p>
          Totol amount = <p id="total_amount"></p>
```

I guess using onChange this is possible.
The number of checkbox should total depends on what fields check in checkbox
and the amount should total based on amount column and fields that check in checkbox. It is possible?

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` or `onchange` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple events — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Can you help me? I'm out of option I tried.

Comment: It’s a bit difficult to understand what the desired result is, but it seems like you’d like to count checkboxes and / or toggle a group of checkboxes. I’d probably do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/31cye4j5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you to move forward

```js
const toggle = (source) => {
  const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]');
  checkboxes.forEach(cb => {
    cb.checked = source.checked;
  });
  compute();
}

const compute = () => {
  const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]');
  let total = 0;
  let checked = 0;
  checkboxes.forEach(cb => {
    if (cb.checked) {
      checked++;
      const amountElt = cb.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("amount")[0];
      total += parseInt(amountElt.innerText, 10);
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("total_checked").innerText = checked;
  document.getElementById("total_amount").innerText = total;


  if (checked === 0) {
    document.getElementById("selectall").checked = false;
  } else if (checked === checkboxes.length) {
    document.getElementById("selectall").checked = true;
  }
}

document.getElementsByName('product_id[]').forEach(cb => {
  cb.addEventListener('change', compute);
});
```

```html
<table class="table" name="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><input id="selectall" type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
      <td>Jessica</td>
      <td class="amount">5200</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
      <td>Jessica</td>
      <td class="amount">800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
Number of checkbox = <span id="total_checked"></span>
</p>
<p>
Total amount = <span id="total_amount"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks for your response but my amount value is not in the lastelementchild can you help me to set the amount through assigning the ID?

Comment: can you fix your question to show where the amount is?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've update my snippet and I just added another column in my table. it seems the total amount would be trigger in the last element of the table , but i want to trigger the amount without using lastelementchild since in my real table my amount is not place in the last, thanks in advance

Comment: is it always in the 4th column? otherwise, you need a class (or some thing) to locate it

Comment: thanks for your response Yes I think it's only define using class but how can I ?

Comment: I have updated my solution, please cross check. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your checkboxes in a `<form>`, you can listen for a `change` event.

On that `<form>`'s change event, you can filter all your checkboxes to get just the ones that are checked. You can get the value of `total_checked` from this filtered array's `length` property.

If you add a class to your amount `<td>`, it will be easier to make the adjacent selection from the checkbox.

Here I've used `checkbox.closest('tr').querySelector('.amount')` to get the string value from the text within the adjacent `<td>`.

Looping through the checked checkboxes, you can keep a running total of the values, taking care to convert the strings to numbers.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const mainCheckbox = document.querySelector('#main_checkbox')
let otherCheckboxes = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]')
const totalCheckedText = document.querySelector('#total_checked')
const totalAmountText = document.querySelector('#total_amount')


mainCheckbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  otherCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.checked = event.currentTarget.checked
  })
})

form.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const checked = Array.from(otherCheckboxes).filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
  let totalAmount = 0
  checked.forEach(checkbox => {
    const amount = Number(checkbox.closest('tr').querySelector('.amount').innerText) || 0
    totalAmount += amount
  })

  totalCheckedText.textContent = checked.length
  totalAmountText.textContent = totalAmount
})
```

```html
<form>
  <table class="table" name="table" id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><input id="main_checkbox" type="checkbox" /></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Jessica</td>
        <td class="amount">5200</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Jessica</td>
        <td class="amount">800</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  Number of checkbox =
  <p id="total_checked"></p>
  Total amount =
  <p id="total_amount"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your elements through a loop and eventlistener then a conditional to check if the inputs are `:checked` if they are, increment/decrement the iterator to track the checked items and addition/subtraction of amounts.

```js
let totalChecked = document.querySelector('#total_checked')
let totalAmount = document.querySelector('#total_amount')
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
let i = 0
let amount;
inputs.forEach( input =>{
  input.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if(e.target.checked){
      totalAmount.textContent = Number(totalAmount.textContent) + Number(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[2].textContent)
      i++;  
    }else{
      totalAmount.textContent = Number(totalAmount.textContent) - Number(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[2].textContent)
      i--;
    }
    totalChecked.textContent = i;    
  })
})
```

```html
<table class="table" name="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th class="amount">Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Jessica</td>
      <td class="amount">5200</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Jessica</td>
      <td class="amount">800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
Number of checkbox = 
<p id="total_checked"></p>
Totol amount =
<p id="total_amount"></p>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I think this is the exact solution that I want but your missing checkall the checkbox in the header part, can you make checkbox in header check those checboxes?