# How do I create show/hide elements for different buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML Code...the buttons interfere with each other. How can I fix this?

---

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" style="margin-left:50px;"> Click Here For Help </button> <br> <br>
          <div id="help1"> 
            <p> Help </p>
          </div>

<button onclick="myFunction()" style="margin-left:50px;"> Click Here For Help </button> <br> <br>
          <div id="help2"> 
            <p> Help </p>
          </div>
```

Javascript shown with ids for the different buttons. Onload section to hide the content on page
load.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("help1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
  x.style.display = "none";
  }
  }
  window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("help1").style.display = 'none';
  };
</script>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("help2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
  x.style.display = "none";
  }
  }
  window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("help2").style.display = 'none';
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Pick distinct function names? Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of changing the `style` directly.

Answer (score 0):

One was is to simply pass the `id` of the element as an input to `myFunction` so the corresponding element can be retrieved from the document and set to `display:none`. This will save you from needing duplicate functions. Press the blue <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button below to see the results.

### Method 1:

```js
function myFunction(ID) {
  var x = document.getElementById(ID);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}


window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("help1").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("help2").style.display = 'none';
};
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('help1')" style="margin-left:50px;"> Click Here For Help </button> <br> <br>
<div id="help1">
  <p> Help </p>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction('help2')" style="margin-left:50px;"> Click Here For Help </button> <br> <br>
<div id="help2">
  <p> Help </p>
</div>
```

---

### Alternative Method:

This example reduces the amount of JavaScript but slightly increases the amount of HTML `id` tags and classes. It also incoporates some additional CSS. As suggested in the comment above this method uses:

• Event listeners
• Toggles a class using `classList`

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("help" + String(this.id.split("_")[2])).classList.toggle("Display_It");
}


window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("Toggle_Button_1").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
  document.getElementById("Toggle_Button_2").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
};
```

```css
#Toggle_Button_1,
#Toggle_Button_2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.Help_Panel {
  display: none;
}

.Display_It {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="Toggle_Button_1"> Click Here For Help </button>
<br>
<br>

<div class="Help_Panel" id="help1">
  <p>Help</p>
</div>

<button id="Toggle_Button_2"> Click Here For Help</button>
<br>
<br>

<div class="Help_Panel" id="help2">
  <p>Help</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelTr7! Just what I needed.

Comment: @Mark H No problem, happy to help.