# Why does this code using `removeEventListener` not seem to unbind key events correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, removeeventlistener

### What I expect my code to do

When I click the first button and then hit the <kbd>Space</kbd> key, it should alert `"hello world"`. When I click the second button and then hit the <kbd>Space</kbd> key, I expect it to alert `"hello"`. Repeat that for the third button, and it should alert `"hello3"`.

### What the current result of the code is

When I click the first button, it works: it alerts `"hello world"`. But the problem is when I click the second or third button: it still alerts `"hello world"`.

What is wrong with my code?

```js
function usekeyUp() {
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp);
}

function keyUp(event) {
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp2);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp3);
  
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    alert("hello world")
  }
}

function usekeyUp2() {
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp2);
}

function keyUp2(event) {
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp3);
  
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    alert("hello")
  }
}

function usekeyUp3() {
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp3);
}

function keyUp3(event) {
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp2);
  
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    alert("hello3")
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="usekeyUp()">click</button>
<button onclick="usekeyUp2()">click</button>
<button onclick="usekeyUp3()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, when you hit <kbd>Space</kbd>, all event listeners are still bound (from the button clicks), and each callback is executed in order. If you press the first button, `usekeyUp` binds `keyUp`. Hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> executes `keyUp`, unbinds `keyUp2` and `keyUp3` and alerts `"hello world"`. It does *not* unbind `keyUp`.

If you then click a different button, e.g. the second one, it *additionally* binds `keyUp2`. But if you hit <kbd>Space</kbd>, the event listeners that are currently bound, in order, are `keyUp` and `keyUp2`. First, `keyUp` executes, *unbinding* `keyUp2` and `keyUp3`. Now, no other event listener is bound, but `keyUp` *remains bound*, forever.

There’s a note about this behavior in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#notes):

> If an EventListener is removed from an EventTarget while it is processing an event, it will not be triggered by the current actions. An EventListener will not be invoked for the event it was registered for after being removed. However, it can be reattached.

So, the `removeEventListener`s “work”, but the correct ones are never reached.

If you want to keep using `removeEventListener`, then move the `removeEventListener` lines into the respective `click` events, not the `keyup` events.

Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

```js
document.getElementById("click1").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp1);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp2);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp3);
});
document.getElementById("click2").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp1);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp2);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp3);
});
document.getElementById("click3").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp1);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp2);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp3);
});

function keyUp1(event){
  if (event.code === "Space") {
    alert("hello world")
  }
}

function keyUp2(event){
  if (event.code === "Space") {
    alert("hello")
  }
}

function keyUp3(event){
  if (event.code === "Space") {
    alert("hello3")
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="click1" type="button" value="First"/>
<input id="click2" type="button" value="Second"/>
<input id="click3" type="button" value="Third"/>
```

Since this code is quite [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), a better approach would use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple events — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/4642212).

```js
{
  let currentAlert;

  addEventListener("keyup", ({code}) => {
    if (currentAlert && code === "Space") {
      alert(currentAlert);
    }
  });

  addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
    if(target?.dataset?.alert){
      currentAlert = target.dataset.alert;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input data-alert="hello world" type="button" value="First" />
<input data-alert="hello" type="button" value="Second" />
<input data-alert="hello3" type="button" value="Third" />
```

Comment: thanks for helping me :D i didnt know that inline onclick attributes are bad, i will use eventlisteners instead from now on