# How to make an onclick function work with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to Js and im having some issues with an onclick function. Ive added a button on HTML and then I wanted to make a popup window appear after clicking that button but I just can`t get it right on the js side.

Here are the codes:

HTML

```
<button class="boton1" onclick="mostrarMensaje()">
       <span class="popuptext1" id="myPopup1">Conector PS/2</span>
       <img src="./images/boton2.png" class="img1">
</button>
```

JS

```
$("#boton1").on("click", mostrarMensaje());

function mostrarMensaje() {
    $("#popuptext1").trigger("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already call `mostrarMensaje()` function on HTML `<button class="boton1" onclick="mostrarMensaje()">` so no need to call it from jQuery. Hide your button text when it's load.Instead of  `trigger()`, use `show()` to show your text on button click.

```js
function mostrarMensaje() {
  $(".popuptext1").show();
}
```

```css
.popuptext1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="boton1" onclick="mostrarMensaje()">
       <span class="popuptext1" id="myPopup1">Conector PS/2</span>
       <img src="./images/boton2.png" class="img1">
</button>
```

Note: You are using`#` for class. Use `.` when using class.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `onclick` attribute from the HTML (See [Why are inline event handler attributes a bad idea in modern semantic HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html)) and change your JS code to:

```
$("#boton1").on("click", mostrarMensaje);
```

Your current code calls the function `mostrarMensaje` and passes the return value to `.on`, when you need to just pass the handler function as an argument to the `.on` function.

I'm not going to repeat what Shree said, see their answer for the explanations for the other issues.

Full Code:

```js
$(".boton1").on("click", mostrarMensaje);
function mostrarMensaje() {
  $(".popuptext1").show();
}
```

```css
.popuptext1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="boton1">
       <span class="popuptext1" id="myPopup1">Conector PS/2</span>
       <img src="./images/boton2.png" class="img1">
</button>
```