# Get parent form of submit button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the parent form of the submit button. Since the ID is produced dynamically, I won't know it. I am sure there is a better way to do this so other suggestions are fine as well, but if it can be done my way I would also appreciate it.

**Form:**

```
<!--Form for sending policy reminders to users-->
<form id="sendReminderForm{{ user.id }}" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="policyId" value="{{ policy.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ user.id }}">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
            onclick="sendReminder(event)"
            type="submit">
        <span class="fa fa-paper-plane"></span> Remind
    </button>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
// Send Policy notification to user
function sendReminder(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = new FormData(e.target.name.get(0));

    $.ajax({ ...
```

Comment: `e.target.closest('form')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `id` of the form containing the `button` which was clicked by reading the `form.id` property from the event `target`:

```js
function sendReminder(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let formId = e.target.form.id;
  console.log(formId);
}
```

```html
<form id="sendReminderForm{{ user.id }}" method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="policyId" value="{{ policy.id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ user.id }}">
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="sendReminder(event)" type="submit">
     <span class="fa fa-paper-plane"></span> Remind
   </button>
</form>
```

*However* it's worth noting that using `onclick`, and the other `onX` event attributes, are no longer good practice and should be avoided.

The better method to achieve your goal is to use unobtrusive event handlers like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(form => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let formId = e.target.id;
    console.log(formId);    
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="sendReminderForm{{ user.id }}" method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="policyId" value="{{ policy.id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ user.id }}">
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" type="submit">
     <span class="fa fa-paper-plane"></span> Remind
   </button>
</form>
```

Here's the same logic as above in jQuery, as you tagged it in the question:

```js
$('form').on('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sendReminderForm{{ user.id }}" method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="policyId" value="{{ policy.id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ user.id }}">
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" type="submit">
     <span class="fa fa-paper-plane"></span> Remind
   </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Would you happen to know why the OnX events are no longer good practice?

Comment: There's a variety of reasons, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742769/519413) covers the basic points, but there are longer more in depth articles online