# Targeting the same class but avoid running the function together

Tags: javascript

Let's say I got three buttons and four iframes where the purpose of the button is to control the iframe width. Each iframe will have the same class `.resize` since the function they need is the same, so I just use `querySelector` to target them.

What's the best way to do this where the button only affects the respective iframe? I have thought of just creating as many classes as possible to different iframe and the function will be the same. But clearly, this will not make sense if I got 100 iframes then I will need to make 100 classes and 100 identical functions.

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return;
  const wasChange = e.target.matches(':first-child'); 
  const styles = ['90px', '60%', '100%'].indexOf(e.target);
  iframe.style.width = styles[index];
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

#iframe01 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#iframe02 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#iframe03 {
  background-color: green;
}

#iframe04 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe01"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe02"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe03"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe04"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to

- [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html)
- iterate over the elements using JavaScript and, on click, dynamically navigate to the associated `<iframe>` in the same container. Event delegation would work well too here.

```js
document.querySelector('#hr').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // if the click was on a change or back button:
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return;
  const wasChange = e.target.matches(':first-child'); // true if "change", false if "back"
  const iframe = e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  iframe.style.width = wasChange ? "90px" : '100%';
});
```

```css
#hr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

#iframe01 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#iframe02 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#iframe03 {
  background-color: green;
}

#iframe04 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="hr">
  <div>
    <div class="hr">
      <button>Button01-change</button>
      <button>Button01-back</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe01" class="resize"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="hr">
      <button>Button02-change</button>
      <button>Button02-back</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe02" class="resize"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="hr">
      <button>Button03-change</button>
      <button>Button03-back</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe03" class="resize"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="hr">
      <button>Button04-change</button>
      <button>Button04-back</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe04" class="resize"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, what if I need one more button which is 60%?

Comment: I've tried `iframe.style.width = wasChange ? "90px" :  "60%" : '100%';` but it's not workingI've edit the snippet, you can have a look.

Comment: Use an array of styles instead, and look up the index of the clicked button in the array. `const styles = ['90px', '60%', '100%']` and `const index = [...e.target.parentElement.children].indexOf(e.target)` to find the style to apply

Comment: Sorry because I'm still learning JavaSript, I was trying to understand your code and apply it. I already understand your concept here but have no idea how to write/implement the code...Would you mind updating your answer

Comment: Once you have the index, just look up the value in the array and assign to the style. `frame.style.width = styles[index];`

Comment: I've just updated the snippet but it's weirdSorry if I make something stupid because I'm really learning JavaScript...

Comment: You need to spread the children into an array, as in the code in the comment. `[...e.target.parentElement.children]`, not `e.target.parentElement.children]`

Comment: I still can't understand...Sorry

Comment: Maybe can you just update the answer or add an updated answer below the original answer we can easily understand, please?