# JavaScript(ReactJS) 1) console.log in classes and 2) function called through another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class, identifier

I have these two questions concerning JS. I must say I've really done my research but couldn't find anything about them.
The questions are:

1. Why can't `console.log` and variable identifiers(`var`, `let`, `const`) be used inside a class, outside of functions/methods?
   E.g.(pseudo code):

```
class App extends Component {
    console.log(this) <--* ['Unexpected keyword or identifier']
    let a = 1         <--* ['Unexpected token']
    state = {         <--* [variable without identifier is alright]
        characters: [
            {
                name: 'Charlie',
                job: 'Janitor'
            }, etc...
            
    }

    removeCharacter = (index) => {
        console.log(this)  <--* [works here normally]

        const characters = this.state.characters

        etc...
            })
        })
    ...
}
```

2. Why does a function needs another function to be called? I mean, in what situations does it become necessary? This comes from something like:

```
const TableBody = (props) => {
    const rows = props.characterData.map((row, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
                <td>{row.job}</td>
 [this] *-->    <button onClick={() => props.removeCharacter(index)}>Delete</button>
            </tr>
        )
 [instead of something like] *--> <button onClick={props.removeCharacter(index)}>Delete</button>
```

I mean, `props.removeCharacter(index)` is itself a call already, isn't it?

Thank you!

Comment: This site only permits you to ask one question per post. VTC

Comment: My bad. Should I delete it? I'm asking honestly because there's already a (good) answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
class TheClass {
  theProperty = 'theValue'
```

as part of [class field syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields), which is syntax sugar for

```
class TheClass {
  constructor() {
    this.theProperty = 'theValue'
```

It's only for assigning properties to the instance, and nothing else.

`console.log(this)` doesn't work because it doesn't make sense there - it's not assigning a property, it's just a floating expression.

`let a = 1` doesn't work because you can't declare a new variable there - the `{` of a class doesn't create a new block. Using class fields assigns to properties of the instance, and doesn't create new standalone identifiers.

> Why does a function needs another function to be called?

In this situation, it's needed because you need to pass an argument. If `removeCharacter` didn't accept an argument, you could do

```
<button onClick={props.removeCharacter}>
```

But it does accept an argument, which is expected to be the index. But the default argument that gets passed to a click handler is the *event*.

You can't do

```
onClick={props.removeCharacter(index)}
```

because that would invoke `removeCharacter` immediately. It'd be equivalent to

```
const result = props.removeCharacter(index);
// ...
<button onClick={result}
```

which isn't the logic that's needed - you want `removeCharacter` to be called when the button is clicked, not when the button is created.

Comment: First off, thank you very much. Now, when you say "new variable", what does it mean? I understand React makes use of the 'state' variable (I tried changing its name and it crashes, so I guess it has to be called so), but I can add other variables without raising any errors as long as they're not preceded by let, const or var. If this is too basic, I'd be more than happy with a reading recommendation.

Comment: I should've said "new identifier" to be precise - a standalone name associated with a value. With class components, state is *not* a variable - rather, it's a property of the instance. Eg you refer to `this.state` to retrieve it, not to `state` by itself.

Comment: Nice! I should mention my background is Python and this is even making Python classes clearer to me ("the { of a class doesn't create a new block." was clarifying to say the least). I guess what got me was that Python won't complain about having, say, `print()` lying around purposeless.

Comment: this event=function behavior isn't valid for regular HTML, correct? In regular HTML I guess function calls must be passed to events, instead of a function's reference as in React. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Inline handlers are a bit like strings that get `eval`ed as the handler, rather than passing in the handler itself, so yes, it's a bit different - but you should never, ever be using inline handlers anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked