# onclick function doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to update the number of participants by increasing it by one every time the submit button gets clicked, and by doing so I added an add() inside my script tag and increased the participant number every time it gets clicked. But the number of participants doesn't get changed for some reason.

Btw I'm new to DOM and JS

```js
let Agenda_style = document.querySelector('.agenda'); //to add style  you must acess the class name/ID using querySelector
Agenda_style.style.color = "red "; // set color to red to change the color of the class agenda
let NewElement = document.createElement("li "); //create new element of type <li>
NewElement.innerText = "Here "; // add a text inside the <li> element 
Agenda_style.append(NewElement); // append a tet to the agendaa class

let participant = 0;

function add() {
  participant++;
  document.getElementById("submit").innerText = participant;
};
```

```html
<h5>Number of participant:<span id="submit">0</span></h5>
<button type="button" onclick="add()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events.
Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_—_dont_use_these) instead.
[What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905)
Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Comment: Your HTML has a closing `</div>` which was never opened.

Answer (score 1):

It fails for me, as I have now `.agenda` element.. do you have that in your HTML?

If I put a null check around that section of the script, the remaining piece works.

```
<h5>Number of participants: <span id="submit">0</span></h5>
    <button type="button" onclick="add()">Submit</button>
</div>
<script>
    let Agenda_style = document.querySelector('.agenda'); // to add style you must access the class name/ID using querySelector

    if(Agenda_style != null) { // only proceed if Agenda_style exists
        Agenda_style.style.color = "red "; // set color to red to change the color of the class agenda
        let NewElement = document.createElement("li "); // create new element of type <li>
        NewElement.innerText = "Here "; // add a text inside the <li> element 
        Agenda_style.append(NewElement); // append a tet to the agendaa class
    }

    let participant = 0;

    function add() {
        participant++;
        document.getElementById("submit").innerText = participant;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that's right it worked for me too. But why does the commented code prevent the function add from working? and how can I make them all works at the same time

Comment: If you look in your console you'll see this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')` .. `Agenda_Style` is `null / undefined`. I will amend my answer code above to put a null check around that code, rather than comment it out.. then once it does exist in the DOM it will work

Answer (score 0):

These days we tend to not use inline JavaScript, so it would be best to grab your button with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and then use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to call your function when it's clicked. This way there's a "separation of concerns" between your mark-up, your CSS, and your code.

```js
const number = document.querySelector('#number');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', add, false);

let participant = 0;

function add() {
  number.textContent = ++participant;
}
```

```html
<h5>Number of participant:
  <span id="number">0</span>
</h5>

<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be working

```
function add() {
  let val = document.querySelector('#submit').innerText;
  val = parseInt(val)+1;
}
```

Comment: I have added the id attribute to the button but it didn't change anything!

Comment: Any errors it showed?

Comment: `id="submit"` is on the `<span>`. It’s not supposed to be the `<button>`.

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't increase "the Number of participant"

Comment: Just check now. I have updated the answer