# Style is not defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7zfN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IojXo.png)

how document.getelementbyclassname("but") I'm not able to modify the style inside the function. when i try to run the code i get this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egnrQ.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, add a [mcve] **as text**.

Comment: Instead of changing CSS via JS, use CSS classes, e.g. `.parentCls .but { border: 1px solid #dddfe2; }`; then [`theParent.classList.toggle("parentCls")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991) way to listen for events.
Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_—_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use `getElementsByClassName` you are getting an array of elements. To fix your error, make sure to select the element you need, e.g.:

```js
inputstxt[0].style.border = ..
```

Or if you want to apply the new styles to all:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < inputstxt.length; i++) {
   inputstxt[i].style.border = ..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`cannot set properties of undefined` means that you are trying to read the style of an Array instead of an element. So you would need to `document.getElementsByClassName("but")[i].style //i is any index` to get/set the style.

Comment: FYI, the downvote was probably not for the correctness of your answer, but the fact that you answered a poor quality question. Doing so encourages more such questions.

Comment: @isherwood Or for the fact that there are _far_ better options than targeting one specific element to change its CSS properties.

Comment: _“Why would you downvote the answer then?”_ — As the comment said: _“Doing so encourages more such questions.”_. _“Why not the question?”_ — Who says the question wasn’t downvoted?