# what is the meaning of onsubmit="return false" ? why onsubmit="false" not working? what is the difference between them?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

**formValidation() function return false but not preventing form submission**

```
<body>
    <script>
        function formValidation(){
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <form onsubmit="formValidation()" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
        <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

**When i have used return front of formValidation() function it is working**

```
<body>
    <script>
        function formValidation(){
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <form onsubmit="return formValidation()" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
        <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: i presume that event attribs turn into event handlers like `function(event){with(this){[attr]}}`, so the `return` sets a return value in that anon function.

Answer (score 0):

Inline handlers like these essentially turn into a function body. Said function is executed when the event is fired.

```
function theHandler() {
  // Attribute string goes here
}
```

If the function returns false, the event's default action (such as submitting the form) is prevented.

```
<form onsubmit="formValidation()"
```

doesn't work because then the constructed function that gets executed doesn't return anything:

```
function theHandler() {
  formValidation()
}
```

But

```
<form onsubmit="return formValidation()"
```

works because then the constructed function is like

```
function theHandler() {
  return formValidation()
}
```

It's somewhat confusing - and is one of the (many) reasons why you should [never use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991) [inline handlers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742769) Attach the event listener properly using JavaScript instead.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', formValidation);
```