# Replacing Div id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the id of a div tag by a new id coming from a queryString.  I have a page that has a few links and I'm passing a unique id to another page to create a unique chart. I want to replace the div name 'replacement' with the new id from the querystring.
Here's what I have so far but it's not working.  Any suggestions? Thx!

```
            <script type="text/javascript"> 

            var newID = getUrlString()["id"];


                $(document).ready(function() {  
                alert(newID);
                                                  $("div.replacement").attr('id', newID);

                    buildChart(newID);
                });


                function getUrlString()
                {
                    var vars = [], hash;
                    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
                    {
                        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                        vars.push(hash[0]);
                        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                    }
                    return vars;
                }

            </script>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           <head>     
           <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>   
           <script type="text/javascript"> 
                google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']}); 
            </script>   

           </head>   
           <body>     
            <div id="replacement" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>  
          </body> 
        </html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the id? If you want to apply a custom style depending on wether the chart is built or not, you could create a container `div` and change its `class`es.

Comment: These answers might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650299/how-do-i-change-the-id-of-a-html-element-with-javascript

Comment: `$("div.replacement")` is a div with class "replacement".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("div.replacement").attr('id', newID);`

should be

`$("#replacement").attr('id', newID);`

Comment: No need to filter the selector  by div