# Change checkbox.id by javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

On my html page I have a `checkbox` with the ID 100:

```
<input type=checkbox id=100 onClick="change2(this)" checked>
```

In the `javascript` I use the ID within the function for a dygraphs chart:

```
function change2(el) {
 chart.setVisibility(el.id, el.checked);
}
```

Problem is that the first dygraphs chart needs to be started by `id=0` for visibility of the series. I have two charts on my site so the first chart use the ID's 0-15 and the chekboxes must have unique ID's.

How can I change the function to manipulate the id of the checkbox? Something like `chart.setVisibility(el.id - 80, el.checked);`

Thanks

Comment: might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650299/how-do-i-change-the-id-of-a-html-element-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since el is a reference of the DOM element, to change its id you can use:

```
el.id = el.id-80;
```

and then pass `el` to your function.

Comment: perfect and so simple...Thanks!