# Very Basic Javascript: Change HTML ID

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to get this to work at: https://jsfiddle.net/xc6htkn4/4/

```
<body>
  <p id="one">One</p>
  <p id="two">Two</p>
  <p id="three">Three</p>
  <p id="four">Four</p>
  <p>
    <button onclick="changeId()">Try it</button>
  </p>  
</body>

#one {
  color: red;
}

#two {
  color: blue;
}

function changeId() {
  var el = document.getElementById('one');
  el.id = 'two';
}
```

What is wrong with the code? It appears to be correct. I am simply trying to change the id on a click event.

Thanks!

Edit: My settings were not appropriately set in jsfiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the ID of a HTML element with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650299/how-do-i-change-the-id-of-a-html-element-with-javascript)

Comment: You cannot set the id to `'two'` because another element already has that id.

Comment: While it isn't best practice, it appears to function correctly. I've updated the code to not have dupe id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is fine, you just need to change the way jsfiddle loads the js code.
Click on "javascript" button and select "Load Type" to be "No wrap - in `<body>`"

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xc6htkn4/5/

Comment: Thanks! Just learning the language. How would this be if I am writing HTML in a real webpage and want to separate my HTML and JS in separate files?

Comment: There should be no problems with it. just create a 'script' element within your 'body' or 'head' tag, and link it to your separate js file: '<script src="scripts/you_site.js"></script>'

Comment: You shouldn't use ID's because ID's are supposed to be used for only one element per page. If you want multiple elements to have the same CSS, use class instead.

Comment: @PavelMorshenyuk what does nowrap do in jsfiddle? What would you use the different options for?

Comment: @paul-fitzgerald You can find this information here: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html?highlight=load%20type#frameworks-and-extensions First two options will not add the functions you declare into global scope. Such functions cannot be called from inline html.