# How to change id value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

**I want to change and revert element id while onclick button.**

**Html** : `<p id="tprice">Price Total: $<span id="order_total">0</span></p>`

Want to change and revert this id="order_total" to this id="rsorder_total" after click on this button:-

```
<input type="button" value="USD" id="myButton"></input>
```

Comment: What is the reason for this? If it is to change the style, just add/remove css classes.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1650299/). But as Get Off My Lawn said, it sounds like you should be using classes rather than IDs.

Comment: usually you don't change elements `id`. If you need to change it because the need to keep track of some attribute or order, then I suggest to use `data-...` attribute, or if it's to change element's style, then use CSS classes as stated in the first comment

Comment:  What he said 100%

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can access your button by the dom and then you can change it.

easily you can add an event listener on the button, then use the dom also. `document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click",
function(){ document.getElementById("order_total").id = "rsorder_total"; });`

Comment: i want to change "<p id="tprice">Price Total: $<span id="order_total">0</span></p>" this element id on clicking on this button "<input type="button" value="USD" id="myButton"></input>
"