# Typescript calling HTML id to change value

Tags: html, typescript

HTML

```
<span id="IDs"> hello </span>
```

.TS

```
changeID(){
  // call IDs and change value

}
```

In TypeScript how do I change the content of id `IDs` that's in my HTML inside my .TS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the ID of a HTML element with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650299/how-do-i-change-the-id-of-a-html-element-with-javascript)

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. When searching for "how to do something" don't limit yourself to "...in typescript".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write basic js technically, but with type of course.

```
changeId() {
  let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('id');
  element.id = newId;
}
```

or just

```
changeId() {
  document.getElementById('id').id = newId;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `element` variable, of course, so no type needed...

Comment: Yes. And? I wrote it that way. If you don't like it you can answer it in your way ;)